# undefined references to inline function

Tags: c, posix, inline, c99

My code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

inline void func()
{
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    func();
    sigset_t oldset;
}
```

If I use the command `gcc main.c` to compile, I got following error:

> main.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `func'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I guess that `inline` is a feature of c99. So I added "`-std=c99`", then I got this:

> $ gcc main.c -std=c99
>
> main.c:13:2: error: unknown type name ‘sigset_t’

How can I get both `inline` and `sigset_t` to work?

Comment: notice that in the former case it is linking that fails; in the latter case it is the *compilation* that fails - i.e. it is *earlier*. It doesn't fix your `inline` bug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000497/whats-the-difference-between-static-inline-extern-inline-and-a-normal-inline-f

Comment: And to fix the bug with `inline` you'll have to [know what it *does*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108159/what-is-the-use-of-the-inline-keyword-in-c)