# Why is Rust unable to find wl_display_get_registry?

Tags: rust, wayland

When writing code to use the Wayland Client API, Rust seems unable to find the `wl_display_get_registry` symbol. An objdump of the file also is unable to find the symbol. However, a C program compiled with GCC is able to find the symbol.

Why can the C program find the symbol, but Rust cannot? How can I fix the Rust program to find the symbol?

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

## Rust

#### Build

```
rustc -o wayland main.rs
```

#### Output

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-m64" "-L" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "wayland.main0.rcgu.o" "wayland.main1.rcgu.o" "wayland.main2.rcgu.o" "wayland.main3.rcgu.o" "wayland.main4.rcgu.o" "-o" "wayland" "wayland.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-l" "wayland-client" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-2da986ecbb2c5327.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-57f46841c9a9f4ee.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-23263fe5893322f6.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-6ed5262c9a0a3e5a.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc_system-99c162b689d43349.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-cd415b85dd267875.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-3876ac10aa96a1e3.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_unicode-598b0e9aca382e9a.rlib" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-4eabb2b1c31071b8.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/myrddin/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-d7a656735ceeae9e.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-l" "dl" "-l" "rt" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "gcc_s" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-l" "rt" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "util" "-l" "util"
  = note: wayland.main3.rcgu.o: In function `main::main':
          main3-317d481089b8c8fe83113de504472633.rs:(.text._ZN4main4main17h52709beaa06fe157E+0x109): undefined reference to `wl_display_get_registry'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

#### Code

```
pub enum WLDisplay {}
pub enum WLRegistry {}

#[link(name = "wayland-client")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn wl_display_connect(name: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char) -> *mut WLDisplay;
    pub fn wl_display_disconnect(display: *mut WLDisplay) -> ();

    pub fn wl_display_get_registry(display: *mut WLDisplay) -> *mut WLRegistry;
}

fn main() {
    let display: *mut WLDisplay;
    let registry: *mut WLRegistry;

    unsafe {
        display = wl_display_connect(::std::ptr::null());
        if display.is_null() == true {
            eprintln!("Unable to connect to the Wayland display server.");
            return;
        }
        println!("Connected to Wayland display server.");

        println!("Retrieving the registry from the Wayland display.");
        registry = wl_display_get_registry(display);
        if registry.is_null() == true {
            eprintln!("Unable to retrieve registry.");
        } else {
            println!("Registry retrieved.");
        }

        wl_display_disconnect(display);
        println!("Disconnected from Wayland display server.");
    }
}
```

## C

#### Build

```
gcc -o wayland -lwayland-client main.c
```

#### Output

```
Connected to Wayland display server.
Retrieving the registry from the Wayland display.
Registry retrieved.
Disconnected from Wayland display server.
```

#### Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wayland-client.h>


int main()
{
   struct wl_display *display;
   struct wl_registry *registry;

   display = wl_display_connect(NULL);
   if (display == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect to the Wayland display server.\n");
      return 1;
   }
   fprintf(stdout, "Connected to Wayland display server.\n");

   fprintf(stdout, "Retrieving the registry from the Wayland display.\n");
   registry = wl_display_get_registry(display);
   if (registry == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to retrieve registry.\n");
   }
   else
   {
      fprintf(stdout, "Registry retrieved.\n");
   }

   wl_display_disconnect(display);
   fprintf(stdout, "Disconnected from Wayland display server.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

## `objdump`

#### Command

```
objdump -TC /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so | grep "wl_display*"
```

#### Output

```
0000000000005f60 g DF .text 0000000000000275  Base wl_display_connect
0000000000006960 g DF .text 0000000000000078  Base wl_display_flush
0000000000006a90 g DF .text 000000000000000c  Base wl_display_dispatch
00000000000067b0 g DF .text 0000000000000042  Base wl_display_cancel_read
00000000000068c0 g DF .text 000000000000000c  Base wl_display_dispatch_pending
0000000000006800 g DF .text 00000000000000bf  Base wl_display_dispatch_queue_pending
00000000000061e0 g DF .text 0000000000000057  Base wl_display_disconnect
0000000000006be0 g DF .text 00000000000000fc  Base wl_display_roundtrip_queue
00000000000068d0 g DF .text 000000000000002c  Base wl_display_get_error
0000000000005610 g DF .text 0000000000000031  Base wl_display_create_queue
0000000000006740 g DF .text 0000000000000052  Base wl_display_prepare_read_queue
0000000000006900 g DF .text 0000000000000051  Base wl_display_get_protocol_error
0000000000005dc0 g DF .text 0000000000000194  Base wl_display_connect_to_fd
00000000000069e0 g DF .text 00000000000000ac  Base wl_display_dispatch_queue
0000000000006ce0 g DF .text 000000000000000c  Base wl_display_roundtrip
0000000000006250 g DF .text 00000000000004f0  Base wl_display_read_events
0000000000006240 g DF .text 0000000000000004  Base wl_display_get_fd
000000000020dce0 g DO .data.rel.ro 0000000000000028 Base wl_display_interface
00000000000067a0 g DF .text 000000000000000c  Base wl_display_prepare_read
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `wl_display_get_registry` function, and several others, are marked as `static inline` in the header file `wayland-client-protocols.h`. [Functions marked `static inline` will not have their symbols exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000497/whats-the-difference-between-static-inline-extern-inline-and-a-normal-inline-f). This explains how C was able to see and use the function but Rust could not.

We must re-implement C macros and static inline functions as Rust functions:

```
pub enum WLDisplay {}
pub enum WLProxy {}
pub enum WLRegistry {}

const WL_DISPLAY_GET_REGISTRY: ::std::os::raw::c_uint = 1;

#[link(name = "wayland-client")]
extern "C" {
    #[no_mangle]
    static wl_registry_interface: WLInterface;

    pub fn wl_display_connect(name: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char) -> *mut WLDisplay;
    pub fn wl_display_disconnect(display: *mut WLDisplay) -> ();

    pub fn wl_proxy_marshal_constructor(
        proxy: *mut WLProxy,
        opcode: ::std::os::raw::c_uint,
        interface: *const WLInterface,
    ) -> *mut WLProxy;
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct WLMessage {
    pub name: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char,
    pub signature: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char,
    pub types: *const *const WLInterface,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct WLInterface {
    pub name: *const ::std::os::raw::c_char,
    pub version: ::std::os::raw::c_int,
    pub request_count: ::std::os::raw::c_int,
    pub requests: *const WLMessage,
    pub event_count: ::std::os::raw::c_int,
    pub events: *const WLMessage,
}

fn wl_display_get_registry(display: *mut WLDisplay) -> *mut WLRegistry {
    let proxy: *mut WLProxy;

    unsafe {
        proxy = wl_proxy_marshal_constructor(
            display as *mut _ as *mut WLProxy,
            WL_DISPLAY_GET_REGISTRY,
            &wl_registry_interface,
        );
        proxy as *mut _ as *mut WLRegistry
    }
}

fn main() {
    let display: *mut WLDisplay;
    let registry: *mut WLRegistry;

    unsafe {
        display = wl_display_connect(::std::ptr::null());
        if display.is_null() == true {
            eprintln!("Unable to connect to the Wayland display server.");
            return;
        }
        println!("Connected to Wayland display server.");

        println!("Retrieving the registry from the Wayland display.");
        registry = wl_display_get_registry(display);
        if registry.is_null() == true {
            eprintln!("Unable to retrieve registry.");
        } else {
            println!("Registry retrieved.");
        }

        wl_display_disconnect(display);
        println!("Disconnected from Wayland display server.");
    }
}
```