# Is `extern` required to make an inline function definition externally linked?

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, inline

GCC can compile and link the following .c files into an executable:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "addsub.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", add(1, 2), sub(1, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

**addsub.c**

```
#include "addsub.h"

inline int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return add(a, -b);
}
```

**addsub.h**

```
#ifndef ADDSUB_H__
#define ADDSUB_H__

int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);

#endif
```

According to **C11**, **6.7.4 Functon specifiers**, paragraph 7:

> *[...]* For a function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a function is declared with an **`inline`** function specifier, then it shall also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the **`inline`** function specifier without **`extern`**, then the definition in that translation unit is an *inline definition*. An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. *[...]*

The `extern` keyword has not been used in any of the function declarations above, so is GCC correct in providing an external definition of the `add` function in "addsub.c"?

In **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**, paragraph 5 says:

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier **`extern`**. *[...]*

However, that does not seem to justify adding external linkage to the inline `add` function when the `extern` keyword is omitted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That seems reasonable. Do you want to post it as an answer (if you think it useful) or do you think I should just delete the question?

Comment: place the 'inline' modifiers in the header file, not on the actual function body (suggest this modifier be applied to both functions, not just one

Comment: however, the 'inlined' function needs to be in the header file, NOT in some other file.  A function in some other file *.c can never be 'inline'd in a different *.c file

Comment: @user3629249 I'm already aware of that. My point of confusion was where the external definition of the function was coming from.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between static inline, extern inline and a normal inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852086) - example of how it compiles with or without (link error) an `extern inline` declaration to instantiate a non-inline version of a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between static inline, extern inline and a normal inline function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000497/whats-the-difference-between-static-inline-extern-inline-and-a-normal-inline-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition “If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the `inline` function specifier without `extern`” is not satisfied because addsub.c includes addsub.h, which contains `int add(int, int);`, which is a declaration of `add` that does not include the `inline` function specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, GCC is acting correctly. But it did not add an external definition of its own accord, you instructed it to.

The key is understanding what an "external definition" is.

> **6.9 External definitions**
>
> 4 As discussed in 5.1.1.1, the unit of program text after
>   preprocessing is a translation unit, which consists of a sequence of
>   external declarations. These are described as ''external'' because
>   they appear outside any function (and hence have file scope). As
>   discussed in 6.7, a declaration that also causes storage to be
>   reserved for an object or a function named by the identifier is a
>   definition.
>
> 5 An external definition is an external declaration that is also a
>   definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an
>   object. If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an
>   expression (other than as part of the operand of a sizeof or _Alignof
>   operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire
>   program there shall be exactly one external definition for the
>   identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

More or less, an external definition is anything that gets defined at file scope. The key to understanding the behavior here is that a function declared with just the `inline` specifier does not provide an external definition. This roughly means that a translation unit doesn't *own* the symbol for this function. So if a program only contains inline definitions of a function, linkage may fail.

Why does it not fail in your case? It's because `addsub.c` includes `addsub.h`. What that translation unit looks like is

```
int add(int, int);
int sub(int, int);

inline int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return add(a, -b);
}
```

The external declaration of `add` at the top makes the "inline definition" be an external definition too. By the very paragraph you quote

> If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation
>   unit include the inline function specifier without extern, then the
>   definition in that translation unit is an inline definition.

Clearly, not every declaration of the function contains just the `inline` specifier (the first declaration in this case), so the definition in `addsub.c` is in fact an external definition.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I accepted Eric's because he got there first with a very concise answer. My point of confusion was indeed a misreading of 6.7.4p7.

Comment: @IanAbbott - No need to explain. I'm glad you got your confusion sorted. I opted to post my answer next to Eric's in the hopes it will help others who are less versed in the standard than you.