# Common way of declaring/defining static, extern and inline functions in C

Tags: c

I know that there are multiple ways to accomplish this, i.e `static` could be used on both the declaration and the definition OR it could only be used on the declaration.

Is this the common way of doing so?

```
// `static` on both the declaration and definition.
static void f1();
static void f1(){}

// `extern` on only the declaration (shared header file).
// then define in a single source file.
extern void f2();
void f2(){}

// `inline` usually doesn't need a declaration, just define it in a shared header file.
inline int f3(){}

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note `extern` is the default for function declarations not marked `static`, so it's optional on `f2`.

Comment: Assume `f2` is a variable instead of a function, then this style would apply right?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: This is the actual question. I.e do I only put `static` in header declarations, or on both declaration and definition, what is the common way of doing this?

Comment: This isn't that difficult of a question, seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Per C 2018 6.2.2 4, if you first declare an identifier for a function with `static`, then all later declarations will treat it as `static` too, even if it is omitted (as long as the first declaration remains visible). So you can omit it. However, I would regard it as bad form, as it may confuse readers. Putting `static` on each declaration (including definitions) would be clearer. I would answer your question, but including `inline` it in complicates things. You might want to edit this question and ask separately about `inline`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, it would be helpful to have them at the same place tho, would appreciate it if you could add the details for inline as well.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think the complication you are talking about is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25000931