# extern keyword for function declarations

Tags: c, extern

My understanding was that "extern" wasn't need when declaring functions in header files. However, I'm looking at the git source code, and I see things like this: (in `cache-tree.h`).

```
void prime_cache_tree(struct index_state *, struct tree *);

extern int cache_tree_matches_traversal(struct cache_tree *, struct name_entry *ent, struct traverse_info *info);
```

What's the difference between these two declarations?

Comment: Or this one: [Is extern keyword for function necessary at all in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255535/is-extern-keyword-for-function-necessary-at-all-in-c).