# Just want to make sure I'm understanding what an external variable is

Tags: c, variables, external

For our assignment we have to code a program in C, but it says not to use external variables in the program. Does this mean variables in other files brought into the main code, or am I unable to use variables in the same file if they're not in the same function? (ie: could I pass a value into a function as an argument and have it return a value that may have to do with a variable in that function and set the return value equal to something, or is that using external variables?)

I've Googled around but it's not exactly clear, and I want to make sure, as this is rather important.

Comment: My guess is that your teacher means global variables - so, most likely, you'll need to pass variables to functions. I would ask your teacher.

Comment: Make sure all of your variables are defined inside of a function.

Comment: With the name you have, there should be a rule preventing you to ask beginner programming questions on the internet :) Your homonym wrote one of the best computer games of all times, at a time when games were programmed by a single person. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lode_Runner

Comment: maybe he means `extern`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable

Comment: @ErikEkman: I would understand the OP's question as "no variables with external linkage", i.e. non-static globals...

Comment: At least it would rule out the use of stdin and stdout ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure, I'd make all my variables part of a function, and either pass them as parameters or return them from the functions.

There are at least two interpretations of *external variables*.

First off, we have the `extern` keyword, which basically symbolizes what you would call a global variable. It's a variable declared in multiple translation unit, but it only exists in one place in memory. It is initialized in a single file and all subsequent changes affect every scope the variable is used in:

```
//globals.cpp
int x = 1337;

//main.cpp
extern int x;

int main()
{
   //x is 1337 here
   return 0;
}
```

The second meaning could be a variable that is declared and defined in class scope, but not used as `extern`. However, you could consider it external to the methods.

```
//main.cpp
int x = 1337; //is this external?
              //could be, remove it just to be safe

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with all the possible cases, because from your question I'm not too sure either:

There is `extern` as a keyword. In order to understand this, you need to understand compilation units. Basically, each file is a compilation unit - so each `.c` is compiled to a `.o` with the headers substituted in place. In each compilation unit, you forward declare symbols you expect to use - functions belonging to other compilation units, for example.

Now, if you declare a global variable in one `.c` file, it is global wrt that file, but does not exist as a symbol in any other file at all - the compiler will error because it doesn't know where that variable was declared.

(Of course, if you declare the variable in a header - it will exist in all of the objects the header is included in, and then the *linker* will sulk, because when it links all the objects up some of the symbols will have the same name).

To get around this, it is possible to define a variable with `extern int x;`, for example. This tells the compiler a) `int x` should be available to this compilation unit, b) `int x` is not *in* this compilation unit and c) the linker should check it exists somewhere in all the units you've put together to form a library or program.

Conceptually, you're doing this all the time with forward-declarations of functions. There's just no way to forward declare a variable. In fact, you can [do this with functions too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions) and not bother r.e shared headers, although this is not really a good idea.

---

The other case is that "external variables" mean something external to a certain scope or module you have. I would check your assignment very carefully and if in doubt ask - whoever set it should be able to explain to you exactly what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

An external variable is a variable with external linkage.

A variable with external linkage is a variable defined at file scope without the `static` keyword.

```
int bla = 0;           // external variable
static int blop =  1;  // non-external variable

int main(void)
{
    return bla
}
```

Note that a variable declared with the `extern` keyword doesn't necessarily have external linkage. Like `const` does not mean constant in C, `extern` does not mean external.

People often use the word external to say that a variable is actually declared in the current translation unit but is defined in another translation unit.