# extern declaration and function definition both in the same file

Tags: c, declaration, extern, function-declaration

I was just browsing through `gcc` source files. In `gcc.c`, I found something like

```
extern int main (int, char **);

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
```

Now my doubt is `extern` is to tell the compiler that the particular function is not in this file but will be found somewhere else in the project. But here, definition of `main` is immediately after the `extern` declaration. What purpose is the `extern` declaration serving then?

It seems like, in this specific example,  `extern` seems to be behaving like `export` that we use in assembly, wherin we export a particular symbol outside of the module

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the `extern` - it does *not* tell the compiler the definition is in *another* file, it simply declares that it exists without defining it. It's perfectly okay for it to be defined in the *same* file.

C has the concept of declaration (declaring that something exists without defining it) and definition (actually bringing it into existence). You can *declare* something as often as you want but can only define it once.

Because functions have external linkage by default, the `extern` keyword is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Functions are implicitly extern in C. Including `extern` is just a visual reminder. Side note, to make a function not extern you can use the `static` keyword.

Comment: Yup.  Use extern when doing something non-standard.

Comment: @user246672 What kind of non-standard things would this be applicable to?

Answer (score 3):

In a function declaration, `extern` simply declares that the function has external linkage, which is the default; the `extern` keyword is utterly useless in this context, and the effect is identical to a normal declaration/prototype without the `extern` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings likely suggested a function prototype was missing. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }
```

is already a declaration is the prototyped syntax of the function `main` with external linkage. This means a prototyped declaration with `extern` just before the `main` definition is redundant.