# Extern functions in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c

In `*.h` header files of a `C` library, should one declare functions

```
extern void f();

// or only 

void f();
```

1. when using only in `C`
2. when using from `C++`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's [almost] never any need to use the keyword `extern` when declaring a function, either in C or in C++. In C and in C++ all functions have external linkage by default. The strange habit of declaring functions in header files with `extern` probably has some historical roots, but it has been completely irrelevant for decades already.

There's one [obscure?] exception from the above in C, which is probably not directly related to what you are asking about: in C language (C99) if in some translation unit a function is defined as `inline`  and also declared as `extern` (an explicit `extern` is used) then the inline definition of that function also serves as *an external definition*. If no declarations with explicit `extern` are present in the translation unit, then the inline definition is used as "internal" definition only.

P.S. There's such thing as `extern "C"` in C++, but that is a completely different matter.

Comment: today the `extern` keyword is often used to bind C/C++ code to Java through the JNI, this is a common solution when using C/C++ with Android, for example.

Comment: @user827992: I'm pretty sure you are talking about `extern "C"` and not the `extern` when declaring a function.

Answer (score 26):

> In header files of a C library, should one declare functions:
>
> ```
> extern void f();
> // or only
> void f();
> ```

#### Issue 1: Semantics

In a C++ program, the functions are declared as functions returning no value and taking no arguments.

In a C program prior to C23, the functions are declared as functions returning no value and taking an indeterminate but not variable-length list of arguments.  In C23, the meaning is the same as in C++.

To get the 'no arguments' meaning in C, use one of:

```
extern void f(void);
void f(void);
```

The same notation also means the same thing in C++, though for pure C++ code, using `void` in the argument list is not idiomatic (do not do it in pure C++ code).

#### Issue 2: Inter-working between C and C++

Tricky, but the normal rule would that you should declare the functions to C++ code as `extern "C"`.  To use the same source code for both, you then need to test the `__cplusplus` macro.  You'd normally do something like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C       extern "C"
#define EXTERN_C_BEGIN extern "C" {
#define EXTERN_C_END   }
#else
#define EXTERN_C       /* Nothing */
#define EXTERN_C_BEGIN /* Nothing */
#define EXTERN_C_END   /* Nothing */
#endif

EXTERN_C void f(void);

EXTERN_C_BEGIN
    void f(void);
    int  g(int);
EXTERN_C_END
```

The options and variations are manifold, but the header can be used by both C and C++.

The macros would normally be defined in one general-purpose header that's used everywhere, and then the particular header would ensure that the general purpose header is included and then use the appropriate form of the macro.

#### Issue 3: Style

Formally, there is no need for the `extern` notation before a function declaration.  However, I use it in headers to emphasize that it is a declaration of an externally defined function, and for symmetry with those (rare) occasions when there is a global variable declared in the header.

People can, and do, disagree over this; I go with the local rules — but when I'm the rule-maker, the `extern` is included in a header.

Comment: It was my fault they were missing the ';' I have fixed the question.

Comment: Thanks for the careful edit, @LokiAstari.  I see how the question got to be as it was, and your edit to my answer made sense.  (I'd made a mild error in the last sentence, which is why it is now last edited by me once more.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler +1 for issue three, I didn't think you had to have extern (except for the extern "C" in C++). (updated) I prefer to omit the extern in headers and use the rule: if it is static it is *not* public, if it isn't static its public. I would say to the OP, one should declare functions void foo(void); but it is best to go with the local rules on this.  Also, I agree only define static functions within the .c file, not in the .h file.

Answer (score 5):

For general use declare as

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void f(void);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Otherwise, `extern` is obsolete.

Comment: Maybe you should add that nifty define '#ifdef _CPLUSPLUS' (or whatever your compiler uses to differ between CPP and C-mode).

Comment: now C++11 add new semantic meaning for extern keyword, like `extern template`.

Answer (score 1):

The latter is perfectly fine, since it's only a function definition, which tells those, who include this header: 'There's a function with this prototype somewhere around here'

In this context, functions differ clearly from variables, but that's a different matter.
Make sure though, that you do not include the function body, unless you declare it 'inline' or as part of a class definition (C++) or as a 'template function' (also C++).

Answer (score 1):

Specifying extern in function prototype has no effect, since it is assumed by default. Whenever a compiler sees a prototype, it assumes a function is defined somewhere else (in the current or another translation unit). This holds for both of the languages.

The following thread has some useful comments in general about extern.

[Effects of the extern keyword on C functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions)