# Function declared twice in C header file

Tags: c, function, header, extern

I'm aware of the declaration of C header files with #ifdef and the meaning of extern before variables and functions. But recently I've got a third party library for an embedded device with the following scheme:

```
/* "lib.h" */
#ifndef LIB_H_
#define LIB_H_

   #ifdef LIB_C

      void function1();
      /* ... */

   #else

      extern void function1();
      /* ... */

   #endif

#endif /* LIB_H_ */
```

And additionally I've got a corresponding C source file:

```
/* lib.c */
#define LIB_C
#include "lib.h"

void function1()
   {
   /* ... */
   }

/* ... */
```

So here I am and a bit confused. What is the reason to declare all functions twice in the header in this way?

Comment: Hmm.. this is interesting....IIRC, functions are external linkage, by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extern functions in C vs C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712707/extern-functions-in-c-vs-c)

Comment: In general, code like that is dangerous.  It means that somewhere in the two sections there is probably a significant difference (not merely the presence or absence of `extern`) between some functions for 'inside the library' and 'outside the library'.  That's a problem because having the 'inside' code use the same definitions as the 'outside' code uses ensures that the two are synchronized — so if there's a difference, there could be a problem that the compiler won't diagnose. Note that the declaration isn't a prototype; it's merely a function with unspecified argument list (but no ellipsis).

Comment: I'd say the most likely explanation is that the person who wrote the code didn't know C in detail. Putting an `extern` before your function declarations can even startle intermediately experienced C programmers. It's good for posing. Kind of the same thing as declaring your local variables as `auto`.

Answer (score 4):

It's either an affectation, or a compatibility hack for some non-conforming or ancient compiler.  You don't need the `extern` version, but using it is also fine, because function declarations are extern by default.

In other words, it's cruft, but maybe someone needs that cruft.  We can't know for sure.