# Why is use of an array defined in File1 working in File2 (only declared there),even without "extern"?

Tags: c, global-variables, extern, linkage, storage-class-specifier

Here I have two files `externdemo1.c` and `externdemo2.c`.In the first file,I have declared and initialized a character array `arr` at file scope.But I have declared it in the second file `externdemo2.c` without the `extern` keyword and made use of it there in the function `display()`. Here are my confusions arising from it.Please answer these three:

```
 //File No.1--externdemo1.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include "externdemo2.c"

extern int display();
char arr[3]={'3','4','7'};
//extern char arr[3]={'3','4','7'};

//extern int main()
int main()
{
    printf("%d",display());
}


//File No.2--externdemo2.c

char arr[3];

int display()
{
    return sizeof(arr);
}
```

**1)** Why does the program compile fine even though I have  declared `arr` without the `extern` keyword in `externdemo2.c`?I had read that the default linkage of functions is external,but I am not sure if that's so even for variables.I only know that global variables have `extern` storage class.

**2)** What is the rigorous difference between `extern storage class` and `extern linkage`.I badly need a clarification about this.In the first file,where I have defined the array `arr`,I haven't used the keyword `extern`, but I know that it has `extern storage` class by default.But in the second file, isn't there any default `extern` ,storage class or linkage,about the global variable `arr`,ie, in `externdemo2.c`?

**3)** Check the commented out line in the first file `externdemo1.c`.Just to test it, I had used the line `extern char arr[3]={'3','4','7'};`.But it gives the error `'arr' initialized and declared 'extern'`.What does this error mean? I have also mentioned a commented line `extern int main()`,but it works fine without error or warning.So why can we use `extern` for a function even though a function is `extern` by default,but not for a variable,like `arr` here?

Please take some time to bail me out over this.It will clear most of my lingering doubts about the whole `extern` thing.It will be immense help if you can answer all 3 bits **1),2) and 3)**. `Especially 3) is eating my brains out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main questions

1. Basically, because you've included the source of `externdemo2.c` in the file `externdemo1.c`.
2. This is the big question.  Because there is no initializer, the line `char arr[3];` in `externdemo2.c` generates a tentative definition of the array `arr`.  When the actual definition with initialization is encountered, the tentative definition is no longer tentative — but neither is it a duplicate definition.

   Regarding `extern storage class` vs `extern linkage`...Linkage refers to whether a symbol can be seen from outside the source file in which it is defined.  A symbol with `extern linkage` can be accessed by name by other source files in which it is appropriately declared.  To the extent it is defined, `extern storage class` means 'stored outside of the scope of a function', so independent of any function.  The variable defined with exern storage class might or might not have extern linkage.

   Because it is not defined with the keyword `static`, the array `arr` has extern linkage; it is a global variable.
3. With the commented out line uncommented out, you have two definitions of one array, which is not allowed.

I observe that you must be compiling just `externdemo1.c` to create a program — the compiler is including the code from `externdemo2.c` because it is directly included.  You can create an object file from `externdemo2.c`.  However, you cannot create a program by linking the object files from both `externdemo1.c` and `externdemo2.c` because that would lead to multiple definitions of the function `display()`.

#### Auxilliary questions

> I have placed both files in the [same directory].  If I don't include the second file in the first, then when I compile the first file it gives the error `undefined reference` to display. Since I have used `extern` for that function in the first file, isn't the linker supposed to link to it even if I don't include the second file? Or the linker looks for it only in default folders?

There are a couple of confusions here.  Let's try dealing with them one at a time.

#### Linking

The linker (usually launched by the compiler) will link the object files and libraries that are specified on its command line.  If you want two object files, call them `externdemo1.obj` and `externdemo2.obj`, linked together, you must tell the linker (via the build system in the IDE) that it needs to process both object files — as well as any libraries that it doesn't pick up by default.  (The Standard C library, plus the platform-specific extensions, are normally picked up automatically, unless you go out of your way to stop that happening.)

The linker is not obliged to spend any time looking for stray object files that might satisfy references; indeed, it is expected to link only those object files and libraries that it is told to link and not add others at its whim.  There are some caveats about libraries (the linker might add some libraries not mentioned on the command line if one of the libraries it is told to link with has references built into it to other libraries), but the linker doesn't add extra object files to the mix.

C++ with template instantiation might be argued to be a bit different, but it is actually following much the same rules.

#### Source code

You should have a header, `externdemo.h`, that contains:

```
#ifndef EXTERNDEMO_H_INCLUDED
#define EXTERNDEMO_H_INCLUDED

extern int display(void);

extern char arr[3];  // Or extern char arr[]; -- but NOT extern char *arr;

#endif /* EXTERNDEMO_H_INCLUDED */
```

You should then modify the source files to include the header:

```
//File No.1--externdemo1.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "externdemo.h"

char arr[3] = { '3', '4', '7' };

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", display());
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
//File No.2--externdemo2.c

#include "externdemo.h"

int display(void)
{
    return sizeof(arr);
}
```

The only tricky issue here is 'does `externdemo2.c` really know the size of `arr`?'  The answer is 'Yes' (at least using GCC 4.7.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.3).  However, if the extern declaration in the header did not include the size (`extern char arr[];`), you would get compilation errors such as:

```
externdemo2.c: In function ‘display’:
externdemo2.c:7:18: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘char[]’
externdemo2.c:8:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: I have placed both files in the well-known Windows folder "My documents".If I don't include the second file in the first, then when I compile the first file it gives the error `undefined reference to display`.Since I have used `extern` for that function in the first file, isn't the linker supposed to link to it even if I don't include the second file?Or the linker looks for it only in default folders?

Comment: **THANK YOU**.A **GRANDSLAM** answer.That is exactly what I needed for a long question like mine.It will take me a while to digest what you said,but I can see you have looked into all my concerns.

Comment: Just this much Mr.Leffler.GUI compilation has spoiled me.Can you tell me what is the command using which we can compile the first file `externdemo1.c` in gcc so that the linker links to the object file of `externdemo2.c` if we don't include the second file in the first?

Comment: There are a couple of options.  (a) `gcc -o externdemo externdemo1.c externdemo2.c`, or (b) `gcc -c externdemo1.c; gcc -c externdemo2.c; gcc -o externdemo1 externdemo1.o externdemo2.o`.  I'm assuming the extension of the object files is `.o`; if it is `.obj`, make the appropriate changes to the link line.

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks a bit err. To me the #include "externdemo2.c" line appears invalid.

Following is the correction I have made and it works.

```
    //File No.1--externdemo1.c

    #include <stdio.h>

    extern char arr[3];

    extern int display();

    int main()
    {
        printf("%d", arr[0]);
        printf("%d",display());
    }

    //File No.2--externdemo2.c


    char arr[3]={'3','4','7'};

    int display()
    {
        return sizeof(arr);
    }
```

Please follow the below links for better understanding:

- [Effects of the extern keyword on C functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions)
- [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

Comment: It's perfectly 'valid' — very unorthodox, but syntactically and semantically legal — to have `#include "externdemo2.c"` inside `externdemo1.c`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The compiler says the function `display()` is `undefined`  if I don't include the second file.Isn't the linker supposed to link to it when I use `extern` in the declaration of that function in the first file `externdemo1.c`?Or linker looks only in default folders?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So Mr.Leffler, does the linker looks only in select folders?It is clearly not linking to the second file as if I remove the `#include "externdemo2.c"` part,then the compiler says `display()` is undefined even though I have used `extern` before it in its declaration in `externdemo1.c`,the first file.

Comment: Hi, I used vc++ 2010 compiler and got linker error for display() function. correcting the code worked perfectly fine. Not sure which compiler you used. I did not test it on clang or gcc.

Comment: you can try using the following link to link your files.http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Compiling-multiple-files.html

Comment: @KajalSinha I am afraid you have simply changed the program to deal with the warnings or errors,but not answered my question!!

Comment: @KajalSinha Why would I define `arr` in the second file?I want it to be in the first file and make it work that way.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: Gimme time...I've updated my answer to address your question.  No, the linker is not obliged to spend any time looking for stray object files that might satisfy references; it is expected to link those files and libraries that it is told to link and not add others at its whim.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Last thing.Do you mean we have to mention in the command line's command which files to link to the main file?Even though I have the bad habit of using a GUI (MingW),it would help me to know how things work for referenced objects.Do we have to mention it,something  like `gcc -externdemo1.c -externdemo2.o -o result.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `#include` as shown will make both as one file only. You can check the intermediate file with flag `-E`, as in:

```
gcc -E externdemo1.c
```

Comment: But the compiler says `display()` is undefined if I don't include the second file.I expect the linker to link to that second file even without including the second file.But it's clearly not doing so.BTW edit your answer.The format is bad.The code is in big bold letters.

Comment: u have to compile both file as: gcc-o output extrademo1.c extrademo2.c  and run as ./output