# extern keyword in C on more functions

Tags: c++, c, extern

I would like to include one header file in both C and C++, and I have a function defined in C code and few functions defined in external library.

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void func0();

#if !defined(__cplusplus)
extern {
#endif

void func1();
int func2(int);

} /* extern */
```

This code produces compilation error when compiled from C source file

```
error C2059: syntax error : '{'
```

Is it possible to fix syntax error directly or I have to use some macros?

```
EXTERNCPP void func0();
EXTERNC void func1();
EXTERNC int func2(int);
```

**Edit 1:** 
I do not ask about
[Effects of the extern keyword on C functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions), I just ask if it is possible to fix syntax in easy way. If it is not possible, i could still remove it completely for C part

**Edit 2:**
To clarify what I want to get. If header is included

from C++:

```
extern "C" void func0(); 
extern "C" void func1(); 
extern "C" int func2(int);
```

from C:

```
void func0(); 
extern void func1(); 
extern int func2(int);
```

Comment: Function declarations declare functions with external linkage by default in both C and C++. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @CharlesBailey It's a matter of name mangling and calling conventions rather than of external linkage

Comment: @icepack: So he has that covered with the outer `extern "C"`. I don't understand what the intent of second (invalid) `extern {` construct is.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `extern {`? Where's the matching close brace supposed to go? Which functions are supposed to have C language linkage?

Comment: @CharlesBailey the header already had an "extern" defined for some functions and I am not perfectly convinced if it has/had a reason. The matching close brace should be same for extern "C" and extern, but there is a syntax error.

Comment: There's no difference between the declarations `void func1();` and `extern void func1();` in C (or C++) for that matter. They both declare functions with external linkage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply omit the `extern {` line when compiling as a C header.

Answer (score 3):

`extern {` is not needed.You need to remove it:-

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

void func0();

#if !defined(__cplusplus)

#endif

void func1();
int func2(int);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
void func0();
#endif

#if !defined(__cplusplus)
void func1();
int func2(int);
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

*** [EDIT] answering your last edit**:

```
void func0(); /* included in both versions */

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
void func1(); 
int func2(int);
#endif

#if !defined(__cplusplus)
extern void func1(); 
extern int func2(int);
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

If you want to use `func0` as `extern` in C:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
void func0();
void func1(); 
int func2(int);
#endif

/* C block */
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
extern void func0();
extern void func1(); 
extern int func2(int);
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

If you don't want to use it at all (from C) remove it from the C block

Comment: This header would not not declare func0 for C and func1 and func2 for C++. This is not equivalent to the behaviour with question's header.

Comment: No, declares func0 for c++ and func1, func2 for c, as you mention in your EXTERNC and EXTERNCPP requirements

Comment: `EXTERNCPP void func0(); EXTERNC void func1(); EXTERNC int func2(int);` ?

Comment: From C++: extern "C" void func0(); extern "C" void func1(); extern "C" int func2(int)

Comment: From C: void func0(); extern void func1(); extern int func2(int)

Comment: func0 has no extern "C"

Comment: `func0` is included in both versions without the `extern` keyword, do you understand the difference between `extern`(specifies that it has external linkage) and `extern "C"`(makes a function-name in C++ have 'C' linkage)?