# Calling function in a C++ source file from main

Tags: c++, c, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans IDE for my C++ implementation. I have two source files main.cpp and univ.cpp. And i defined a function show() in univ.cpp. How can i call this function from main. When i call normally like below, i get "show() not in scope".

```
    int main(int argc, char**argv)
    {
       show();
       return 0;
    }
```

I don't want to use a separate header file and define the function. Instead i want to define this function in cpp source file like stated above.

Thanks.

Comment: `return 0` is noise. It's implied.

Comment: @BartoszKP: More like "I don't want a driver's license, I just want to drive the damn car."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effects of the extern keyword on C functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   extern void show();
   show();
}
```

Comment: Functions' declarations have by default `extern`al linkage, hence the keyword is redundant

Comment: @PiotrS.: That's true.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a header for univ called univ.h here would be the code:

```
#ifndef _UNIV_H_
#define _UNIV_H_

void show();

#endif
```

The you will need to include it in both cpp files.

```
#include <univ.h>
```