# Using inline C function is impossible in initializer marked via NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, inline, initializer

Say I have a class like this

```
// DummyObject.h
@interface DummyObject : NSObject

- (instancetype)initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo 
NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@end
```

and

```
// DummyObject.m
inline void
foobar() {}

static inline void
static_foobar() {}

@implementation DummyObject

- (instancetype)initWithFoo:(NSString *)foo
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        // Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
        // "_foobar", referenced from:
        // -[DummyObject initWithFoo:] in DummyObject.o
        foobar();

        static_foobar(); // Works as expected
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

My understanding about **inline** is that it simply suggest the compiler to embed the function body into the calling code instead of executing an actual call. And **static** refers to the scope, which means I can only use this very function inside the file that defines it.

## Update 1:

According to trungduc's comment, "inline foobar" works after change DummyObject.m to DummyObject.mm.

So my current conclusion is

1. If DummyObject is compiled as Objective-C(.m), then "inline foobar" won't work
2. If DummyObject is compiled as Objective-C++(.mm), then "inline foobar" works fine
3. If I delete the "inline" keyword, then "foobar" works fine in both Objective-C and Objective-C++
4. "static inline static_foobar" always works

This is quite confusing, I've checked the Clang documentation with no luck. This has been in my head for about 2 days, any suggestions will help...

Comment: Is this Objective-C?  It doesn't look like C.

Comment: @dbush Yes it is Objective-C, I'm using some structs and C functions inside Objective-C method.

Comment: @NSFish Objective-C doesn't have keyword `inline` as I know. It should be `NS_INLINE` or rename `DummyObject.m` to `DummyObject.mm` to make this file become Objective-C++ file and it will work

Comment: @trungduc Thanks for your reply. DummyObject.mm did work. But I still don't know why Objective-C method can call normal  C functions without problems, yet inline functions won't work...

Comment: @NSFish Because Objective-C is a thin layer atop C, and is a "strict superset" of C, meaning that it is possible to compile any C program with an Objective-C compiler, and to freely include C language code within an Objective-C. You can take a look at Wikipedia for Objective-C https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C

Comment: @trungduc I'm aware of what you said, which doesn't answer my question. Since Objective-C is a thin layer on top of C, the compiler(in this case, Clang), is supposed to recognize any C functions. Yet the example I wrote shows that's not the case, inline C functions are left alone...

Comment: @NSFish You should understand what is difference of between `inline` in C and C++. Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108159/what-is-the-use-of-the-inline-keyword-in-c

Comment: @trungduc Thanks again! This link saves my life . Now I understand.