How to use `inline` function across multiple C files without the "declared but never defined" warnings?
I want to use inline function across multiple C files. Maybe the MWE would be:
main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "file1.h"

// Define the inline function in one of the source files
inline int f(int x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello inline function: %d\n", f(1));

    int y = some_function();

    printf("Hi from file1: %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}

main.h:
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

// Declare the inline function in the header file
extern inline int f(int x);

#endif // MAIN_H

file1.c:
#include "main.h"
#include "file1.h"

// Use the extern inline function in another file
int some_function() {
    return f(3);
}

file1.h:
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

// Declare the some_function function
int some_function();

#endif // FILE1_H

Although it works, I am getting the following
❯ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c file1.c -o file1.o
In file included from file1.c:1:
main.h:5:19: warning: inline function ‘f’ declared but never defined
    5 | extern inline int f(int x);
      |                   ^
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -c main.c -o main.o
gcc file1.o main.o -o main

Although there are many posts related to "declared but never defined" warnings, but none of them were able to tackle this warning in simple terms.
Am I doing anything wrong?

The duplicate is about c++ , not about c. In C there is no one definiton rule - in fact, the inline and non-inline functions may be different. | Why do you want an inline function? Did you research what is an inline linkage and how it works? Do you intend to provide two function definitions of the function, one for inlining and the second for external calls?

in simple terms. If you want simple terms, then do not use inline. It is a thing of the past, not relevant now. Use static and define the function int he header. If you feel like an archeologist, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312597/is-inline-without-static-or-extern-ever-useful-in-c99 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216510/what-does-extern-inline-do or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108159/what-is-the-use-of-the-inline-keyword-in-c .

This is during compilation of file1.c, where the compiler sees an inline function declaration, which is also called but which is never defined. That means that the compiler can't inline it at this point, which is why it's giving you that warning. BTW: inline doesn't automatically inline anything and things can be inlined even without it. What problem are you really trying to solve here?

"Do you intend to provide two function definitions of the function, one for inlining and the second for external calls?" - No. I want to provide one function to be inlined across multiple source files.

"Why do you want an inline function?" - I want to reduce the overhead of function calls and is especially used for small, frequently called functions.

@KamilCuk "It is a thing of the past, not relevant now." - So it is not used in C anymore? It is surprising to me as inline seemed very effective.

inline is just a hint, it is not mandatory. Compilers commonly are really good at optimization, sometimes in combination with linkers. Anyway, to get the result you want, such a function needs to have certain properties, as outlined in the standard, which you would want to read. One important thing is that its definition (not just its declaration) is visible for all translation units.

So it is not used in C anymore? Yes. (I use it to remove one gcc warning). inline seemed very effective why would a compiler inline only functions marked inline? Sounds ineffective. All functions (that compiler can) can be inlined.

Why my compiler complain ?
From C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011):

Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function. For a
function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a
function is declared with an inline function specifier, then it shall
also be defined in the same translation unit.

Because the terminology is a bit confusing, the inline definition acting as declaration of the symbol, and the extern declaration acting as definition of it.
The most easy way to split a inlined function in multiple modules, is to declare it directly in the header file.
Why are some calls not inlined ?
First of all, inlining is an optimization, so non-optimized compilation does not inline.
Some calls cannot be inlined for technical reasons.
Also, certain usages in a function definition can make it unsuitable for inline substitution.
Among these usages are: variadic functions, use of alloca, use of computed goto and use of nonlocal goto
Just because a call can be inlined does not mean it should be inlined.
The GNU C compiler weighs costs and benefits to decide whether inlining a particular call is advantageous.
A function call may be inlined even if not declared inline in special cases where the compiler can determine this is correct and desirable. For instance, when a static function is called only once, it will very likely be inlined.
You can force inlining of all calls to a given function that can be inlined, even in a
non-optimized compilation, by specifying the ‘always_inline’ attribute for the function, like this:
    inline void foo (const char) __attribute__((always_inline));

This is a GNU C extension.

"Because the terminology is a bit confusing, the inline definition acting as declaration of the symbol, and the extern declaration acting as definition of it." - So basically should I put extern inline int f(int x); in main.c and inline int f(int x) { return x; } in main.h?
