# How can i use a function in multiple drivers?

Tags: c, function, prototype

I want to call `do_input_boost` function in another driver but I couldn't find the way to call the function.

```
static void do_input_boost(struct kthread_work *work)
{
    unsigned int i, ret;
    struct cpu_sync *i_sync_info;

    /* Set the input_boost_min for all CPUs in the system */
    pr_debug("Setting input boost min for all CPUs\n");
    for_each_possible_cpu(i) {
        i_sync_info = &per_cpu(sync_info, i);
        i_sync_info->input_boost_min = i_sync_info->input_boost_freq;
    }

    queue_delayed_work(system_power_efficient_wq,
        &input_boost_rem, msecs_to_jiffies(input_boost_ms));
}
```

I also added `EXPORT_SYMBOL(do_input_boost)` but couldn't find the proper prototype definition for calling this function, like

```
do_input_boost();
```

EDIT:
i added a hear and linked in target driver

```
#ifdef CONFIG_CPU_BOOST
extern void do_input_boost(void);
#else
extern void do_input_boost(void)
{
}
#endif
```

Comment: Remove `static` ? Add a [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) before calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you'll have to remove `static` as it limits the visibility of this function to the current translational unit (provided the other **driver** is not in the same `.c` file).

Removing `static` will make that function global and from other `.c` files it will be accessible using `extern` declaration.

lets say that this function of ours `do_input_boost` is defined in `a.c` file and your driver is in `b.c` file (where you want to call that function), then:

in `b.c` you'll declare that function: `extern void do_input_boost(struct kthread_work*);` and then you can call that.

Comment: thank you, i edited my post with added a header. now i can call the function with that way. is it correct?

Comment: @MostafaZarghami Edited my answer.

Comment: by this way how can i call the function? do_input_boost(); ? b.c is compiling if i set "extern void do_input_boost(void);" and "do_input_boost();"

Comment: @MostafaZarghami check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions