# What is the meaning of the "extern" keyword when the function is defined in the same place?

Tags: c, gcc

I am working on some embedded "C" code and encountered liberal use of the "extern" keyword in a project that compiles with the gcc+crossworks compiler

I know conventionally what extern would mean.  But I don't understand why it was made extern here?
Is there some extra meaning that I didn't know about? or is it just a case of someone probably doing
a copy/paste and the compiler ignoring the keyword?

e.g.

```
extern void fnApplicationLanStartup()
{
   // ... code follows
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effects of the extern keyword on C functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856636/effects-of-the-extern-keyword-on-c-functions)

Comment: As to why it's used **exactly** there, I do not know, as I don't see the exact code.

Comment: @Jorengarenar - no it doesn't exactly answer it, but I think I found the answer.  That is, it's superfluous here.