# Should I ever declare a function as extern (explicitly)?

Tags: c, extern

Given that all (non-static) function declarations are `extern` by default, is there any point in preceding a function declaration with `extern` or is it just poor coding practice?

Comment: It's pointless, at least with all environments I'm aware of. [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/856736/898348) may help

Comment: In the professional environment I am working in currently, we are required to declare as `extern` the functions which will be required by other systems. 
All our functions are exposed for testing purposes, but the ones declared as `extern` are explicitely for external use.
There is no technical change, but it makes a 3000-files codebase more readable, knowing which are the internal and which are the exposed functions

Comment: Sometimes it's good to express your intention not only to a computer, but to the person that will be reading the code later as well. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Adalcar Thanks, using extern as a way of better commenting the code. This makes good sense.