# Redefinition allowed in C but not in C++?

Tags: c++, c, declaration

Why does this code work in C but not in C++?

```
int i = 5;
int i; // but if I write int i = 5; again I get error in C also

int main(){

  // using i
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[**Tentative definition is allowed in C but not in C++.**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03tentative_defn.htm)

A tentative definition is any external data declaration that has no storage class specifier and no initializer.

C99 6.9.2/2

> A declaration of an identiﬁer for an object that has ﬁle scope **without an initializer**, and
> **without a storage-class speciﬁer or with the storage-class speciﬁer static**, constitutes a
> tentative deﬁnition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative deﬁnitions for an
> identiﬁer, and the translation unit contains no external deﬁnition for that identiﬁer, then
> the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a ﬁle scope declaration of that
> identiﬁer, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
> equal to 0.

So `int i` is a tentative definition. The C compiler will combine all of the tentative definitions into a single definition of `i`.

In C++ your code is ill-formed due to the [**One Definition Rule**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (Section 3.2/1 ISO C++)

> No translation unit **shall contain more than one definition of any variable**, function, class type, enumeration type or template.

---

> // but if I write `int i = 5;` again I get error in C also

Because in that case it no longer remains a tentative definition because of the initializer (5).

---

Just for the sake of information

> J.5.11 Multiple external definitions
>
> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

Also check out this [excellent post on external variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387).

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: It's illegal in both C and C++ but C compilers implement a C extension for this to work. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6371156/183120) answer.

Comment: @legends2k: It is not illegal in C. This is what the answer menetions "You can have multiple tentative definitions in a **single translation unit** but the effect is the same as having one non-tentative external definition (e.g. something like int a = 0;)."

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: It's undefined behaviour; did you check the [comment by litb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking/1490777?noredirect=1#comment1344020_1490777)?

Comment: @legends2k : No its not because the linkage do not disagree in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Tha is called tentative definition. It's allowed only in C.

> **A tentative definition is any external
> data declaration that has no storage
> class specifier and no initializer.** A
> tentative definition becomes a full
> definition if the end of the
> translation unit is reached and no
> definition has appeared with an
> initializer for the identifier. In
> this situation, the compiler reserves
> uninitialized space for the object
> defined.
>
> The following statements show normal definitions and tentative definitions.

```
int i1 = 10;         /* definition, external linkage */
static int i2 = 20;  /* definition, internal linkage */
extern int i3 = 30;  /* definition, external linkage */
int i4;              /* tentative definition, external linkage */
static int i5;       /* tentative definition, internal linkage */

int i1;              /* valid tentative definition */
int i2;              /* not legal, linkage disagreement with previous */
int i3;              /* valid tentative definition */
int i4;              /* valid tentative definition */
int i5;              /* not legal, linkage disagreement with previous */
```

> **C++ does not support the concept of a tentative definition: an external data declaration without a storage class specifier is always a definition.**

From here: [Tentative Definitions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03tentative_defn.htm)

Answer (score 2):

To understand tentative definition better, go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition)