# Same code, different output in C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, sequence-points

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 11;
            int b = 2;
            a -= b -= a -= b += b -= a;
            System.Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:27

C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
       int a = 11;
       int b = 2;
       a -= b -= a -= b += b -= a;
       std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
       return 0;
}
```

Output:76

Same code has differernt output, can somebody tell why is this so ?
Help appreciated!!

Comment: What is this obsession with asking questions about things that are clearly undefined behavior. Even if the behavior is defined in C#, the code is just silly.

Comment: Who said that values should be same?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C# your code is well defined and is equivalent to the following:

```
a = a - (b = b - (a = a - (b = b + (b = b - a))));
```

The innermost assignments are not relevant here because the assigned value is never used before the variable is reassigned. This code has the same effect:

```
a = a - (b = b - (a - (b + (b - a))));
```

This is roughly the same as:

```
a = a - (b = (b * 3) - (a * 2));
```

Or even simpler:

```
b = (b * 3) - (a * 2);
a -= b;
```

However, in C++ your code gives undefined behaviour. There is no guarantee at all about what it will do.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  The short answer: C# != C != C++.  The longer answer: requires an understanding of ["sequence points"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/14/4374222.aspx)

Comment: @paulsm4 an important note though is that C is a subset of C++, C++ is not a subset of C#.

Comment: @chacham15 No, C is *not* a subset of C++. [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337370/), `int a; int a;` is valid C, but invalid C++.

Comment: @FredOverflow is that the only difference? it just seems like such a nitpick to point that out.

Comment: @chacham15 No, [of course not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/), tentative definitions are just one of many examples.