# What is this double declaration mean in C?

Tags: c, global, local

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redefinition allowed in C but not in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337370/redefinition-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;
int i;
int main()
{
        // int i;
        // int i;
        printf("%d\n",i);
        return 0;
}
~
```

The above code runs wihtout giving any error `gcc -Wall -Werror demo.c -o demo`

But when I uncomment the `local` `i` variables the comment out the `global` `i` ,It gives me errors .

```
In function ‘main’:
demo.c:7:6: error: redeclaration of ‘i’ with no linkage
demo.c:6:6: note: previous declaration of ‘i’ was here
```

What is this local global concept here ?, Anybody Please explain.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Answer (score 2):

In C99 (see more specifically section 6.2), global declarations have by default external linkage (6.2.2§5). In that case (6.2.2§2), both declarations of i refer to the same object. On the contrary, local variables have no linkage (6.2.2§6), and are thus supposed to refer to unique identifiers (again 6.2.2§2): you would thus end up with two local variables of the same name in the same scope, which is not allowed (6.2.1§5: *Different entities designated by the same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name spaces*)

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one definition of your variable in a global scope, if all definitions agree (all have the same type) and the variable is initialized in not more than one place.

> J.5.11 Multiple external definitions
>
> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword extern; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).