# multiple definition in g++?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, g++

The code is as follows:

**global.h**

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#include <stdio.h>
int test;

void test_fun(void);
#endif
```

**global.c**

```
#include "global.h"

void test_fun()
{
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "global.h"

int main(void)
{
    test_fun();
    test = 1;
    printf("%d\n", test);
}
```

**Makefile using gcc compiler**

```
main: main.o global.o
    gcc -o main main.o global.o

main.o: main.c global.h
    gcc -c main.c
global.o: global.c global.h
    gcc -c global.c

clean:
    rm -f global.o main.o main
```

This works well.

However, when I change my code to C++, as follows:

**global.h**

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#include <iostream>
int test;

void test_fun(void);
#endif
```

**global.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"

void test_fun()
{
    cout << test
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"

int main(void)
{
    test_fun();
    test = 1;
    std::cout << test;
}
```

**Makefile using g++ compiler**

```
main: main.o global.o
    g++ -o main main.o global.o

main.o: main.cpp global.h
    g++ main.cpp
global.o: global.cpp global.h
    g++ global.cpp

clean:
    rm -f global.o main.o main
```

The code above throws the output:

```
global.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `test'
```

What makes the different here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redefinition allowed in C but not in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337370/redefinition-allowed-in-c-but-not-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've `int test;` in a header which is included in 2 TUs, hence the error. Both the translation units `main.c` (or .cpp depending upon the compiler used) and `global.c` have `global.h` included, which leads to two definitions of the same variable in two object files, thus the linker error.

Pass `test` as an arguement to `test_fun`, thereby avoiding the usage of a global.

If you absolutely have to share the variable between the TUs, then remove `int test;` from `global.h` and in `main.cpp` do

```
int test;
```

and in `global.cpp` do

```
extern int test;
```

As an aside, since it's a global variable, `test` would be initialized to `0` and hence in `main` when you `test_fun();`, it should print `0` and then after setting it to 1, it'll print `1`.

[It's illegal in both C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking/1490777#comment1344020_1490777) from a language standpoint, but as for why it works with a C compilers (like GCC) is because they implement [a common extension, a legacy cruft](http://c-faq.com/decl/common.html).

Comment: I think you misspelled 'extern'

Comment: Thank you, I know how to avoid this error, but I want to know why the code in `cpp` can't be a `C++` program ?

Comment: @Charles0429: That's because of tentative definitions that C allows; see the last line I just added.

Comment: Thank you @legends2k, the last line solves my question.

Comment: @Charles0429: Glad it helped, however, I found out that it's illegal in C as well, check the last line now, I've updated it with details.

Answer (score 1):

... You are using a different programming language

Comment: I think this doesn't matter whether I use `.c` files or `.cpp` files. I confirmed just now when I replace all `.c` files with `.cpp` files, the result is still the same.

Comment: @Charles0429 - g++ speaks C++, gcc speaks C. Like getting a French man to understand Greek.

Comment: Ed Heal is right. Getting errors with C++ in gcc and vice-versa is easy.

Comment: @Charles0429 - Why not have a go with a Fortran compiler?

Comment: When I renamed the code file to `.cpp`, aren't they using `C++`?

Comment: @Charles0429 - You can rename them to whatever you want. The code is C hence use a C compiler. So why not write a file as hello.french and rename it to hello.german. The computer does not automatically translate bonjour for you.

Comment: Then, what can be called a `C++` program (please show me an example), isn't `C` included `C++`?

Comment: please see my update, I think I have rewritten the code in `C++` now, but the result is still the same.

Comment: I think you should interpret OPs question as: "Why does this code compile as C but produces this error when compiled as C++? It looks to me like it uses the supported C subset of C++."

Comment: C++ supports C, but can behave differently. That's why we have `extern "C"`.