# GCC:Multiple definitions of a global variable doesn't give linker error

Tags: c, gcc, global-variables

I stumbled upon this weird behaviour when compiling C programs using **gcc**.

Let's say we have these two simple source files:

## fun.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// int var = 10;   Results in Gcc compiler error if global variable is initialized
int var;

void fun(void) {
    printf("Fun: %d\n", var);
}
```

## main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int var = 10;
int main(void) {
    fun();
    printf("Main: %d\n", var);
}
```

Surprisingly, when compiled as `gcc main.c fun.c -o main.out` this doesn't produce **multiple definition linker error**.

One would expect **multiple definition linker error** to occur just the same, regardless of global variable initialization.
Does it mean that compiler makes uninitialized global variables extern by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two variables with same name and type, in two different .c files, compile with gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189982/two-variables-with-same-name-and-type-in-two-different-c-files-compile-with-g)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21275992/3049655 ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking

Comment: [This SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095861/about-tentative-definition) might be helpful.

Comment: Related note, when accessing within a shared library, you can find both with dlsym(). This is what the RTLD_NEXT argument is for. I’m not aware of how the order is determined, however.Probably a good practice to avoid it, or share it by defining it once and using the extern keyword in other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global variable can have any number of *declarations*, but only one *definition*. An initializer makes it a definition, so it will complain about having two of those (even if they agree).

Comment: I do not believe you are correct because int var; is a variable declaration and definition. The fact that you can use it right away proves it is also a definition, does it not?

Comment: The C99 standard calls that a "tentative definition"; The "multiple definition" error message (and I) are still using the old K&R terminology.

Comment: Yeah, that is it, as I just found out from @Cool Guy's comment