# Why do I not get a linker error in C++ when I am adding two variables with same name in the global scope in two different translation units?

Tags: c++, variables, linker, namespaces, linker-errors

Person.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std;

int alpha = 5;

int main()
{
    std::cout << alpha << std::endl;
}
```

Person2.cpp

```
int alpha = 10;
```

The command I am using to compile

```
g++ -o '.\Person.cpp' .\Person2.cpp
```

It runs fine and prints '5' but I expected some kind of linker error.

Comment: We do get a linker error. [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Oll2-u3xD) and [2nd demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uOksxzxEbo0hy1uV)

Comment: It's because the compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.  The linker is allowed to assume that all definitions are the same.

Comment: Dupe: [GCC:Multiple definitions of a global variable doesn't given linkner error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040861/multiple-definitions-of-a-global-variable). Also see [one definition rule violation **no diagnostic required**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192170/what-is-the-one-definition-rule)

Comment: It is not linker's responsibility to report an error for the multiple globals with the same name. According to the One definition rule in C++, "In certain cases, there can be more than one definition of a type or a template. A program consisting of multiple header files and source files will typically have more than one definition of a type, but not more than one definition per translation unit.". So you can get error if you put those variables in the same file. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Comment: @DrewDormann: Purely as a technicality, the code is ill formed, but no diagnostic is required (which differs philosophically from UB, but that's about it).

Comment: This is just one of the global variable problems that exist. Best way is to avoid global variables by design.  (You can have global constants `constexpr int default_alpha = 10`). If you want to share state between translation units opt for some kind of dependency injection.