# Extern in C - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

I'm playing around, making a small chessgame in C, cause I haven't touched C for years.

My main is a pretty simple test:

```
#include "ChessGame.h"

int main()
{
    initializeNewGame();
    onLift('a', '2');
    onSet('a', '3');
}
```

`InitializeNewGame()` is going to clear some buffers, and initialize the board. The board is a simple struct, defined in:

**chessBoardStructure.h:**

```
struct chessboard
{
    char board[8][8];
};

struct chessboard* board;
```

When initialize is called, it utilizes a header called Chessboard.h. This header has the responsibility of checking that the user is following the rules. It also knows how to initalize the board.

**chessBoard.c**

```
#include "chessBoardStructure.h"

extern struct chessboard * board;

void initializeBoard()
{
    board = malloc(sizeof(struct chessboard));
    /* Sets the array to the right chars */
 }
```

Now, from my understanding, I should now have defined the global variable, board. And to verify I print out the board after `InitializeBoard()` has been called from `InitializeNewGame()`. All seems fine.

Now the `InitializeGame()` returns to main, and `onLift()` is called. This should verify some rules. The problem is, when `onLift()` is called in ChessGame.c as:

**ChessGame.c**
    extern struct chessboard* board;

```
void onLift(char col, char row)
{

    short err = getValidMoves(liftedCol, liftedRow, &validEndPoints, &validRoads, board);
    if (err == -1)
        handleBadPiece();

    /* Do stuff */

}
```

The board is just full of -51. When I set a watch on the board in the header, I see it being initialized, and then when `InitializeGame()` exits scope, it becomes the good ol' -51.

What am I doing wrong here?

I miss C++. :-)

Thank you!

**Edit small example**
I tried changing the extern around as proposed, but the same thing happened. 
See the below example.

**main.c**

```
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    masterInitialize();
    printData();

    return 0;
}
```

(Headers not shown, due to just declarations)

**a.c**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "struct.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystruct* datastruct;

void masterInitialize()
{
    initializeDataStruct();
}

void printData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("Data: %c\n", datastruct->data[i]);
}
```

**b.c**

```
#include "b.h"
#include "struct.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct mystruct* datastruct;

void initializeDataStruct()
{
    datastruct = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        datastruct->data[i] = 1;
}
```

**struct.h**

```
struct mystruct
{
    char data[10];
};

extern struct mystruct* datastruct;
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Which compiler is this? Which OS?

Comment: malloc doesn't initialize the data, it will contain any random garbage. Why are you using so many spaghetti global variables though?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Visual Studios C compiler, running win10.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, done.

Comment: @BenjaminLarsen where are `a.h` and `b.h` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got things the wrong way around.

This should be in "chessBoard.c".

```
struct chessboard* board;
```

and this should be in your header

```
extern struct chessboard * board;
```

As that'll tell all the files where you include it that there exists the variable `board` declared somewhere and at link time, it'll use the one you've declared in "chessBoard.c"

With the way you have it currently, each C file that includes the header will have it's own unique version of `board`

Comment: Hm, are you sure? As far as I can see, since the variable board isn't initialized, there should be only a single instance of it. Otherwise, since the visibility of the symbol is public, there should be a linker error, but there should never be two separate instances of `board`

Comment: @Ctx there may be multiple extern declarations but there must be one declaration in C which is not extern.

Comment: @tilz0R Yes, but there can be multiple non-extern declarations, which cumulate to a single symbol on linking, provided at most one of these is initialized. As far as I can see, it cannot happen, that two public visible symbols of the same name result in two separate instances of that symbol, as this answer claims.

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. The scope of a variable declared outside of a function is local to the compilation unit. The `extern` keyword is used to say that the variable is declared in another compilation unit.

Comment: @ChrisTurner No, you are wrong here, I just tried to sound a bit diplomatic ;) See my comments above

Comment: @ChrisTurner I tried as you proposed. Having the same problem. 
I've created a small example that does as you propose, but still fails - see the edit :)

Comment: @BenjaminLarsen well...you haven't done as I suggested - you declared the variable in two C files. Should only need it in only one of them

Comment: @ctx that sounds like undefined behaviour - how does it know which of the many variables is the correct one to use?

Comment: @ChrisTurner That's why at most one instance may have an initializer

Comment: @ChrisTurner - that did it!

Comment: @ChrisTurner "The compiler treats function declarations without a storage class specifier as if they included the specifier extern. Similarly, any object identifiers that you declare outside all functions and without a storage class specifier have external linkage"

Comment: @Ctx no you're wrong. Having multiple definitions is undefined behaviour as per C standard, but allowed in POSIX.

Comment: @AntiHaapala Then you should vote down this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189982/two-variables-with-same-name-and-type-in-two-different-c-files-compile-with-g or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking

Comment: @Ctx see this linked from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking

Answer (score 0):

`extern struct chessboard * board;` doesn't *define* anything; it just declares the identifier `board` and that it is of type pointer to `struct chessboard` somewhere.

`struct chessboard* board;` is a (tentative) definition. It defines a single variable with external linkage and static storage duration. However, you've put it into the included source file, which is included in several places. Thus in every place that `#include`s this file will have a conflicting definition of `board`.

GCC on Linux will merge multiple definitions in separate translation units, but the C standard doesn't state that. Instead it says ([C11 6.9](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9p5):

> 5 [...] If an identifier declared with external linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a sizeof or _Alignof operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire program there **shall be exactly one external *definition*** for the identifier; otherwise, there shall be no more than one.

In your code there were multiple *definitions* for the same identifier, which will cause your program to have undefined behaviour, because [C11 4p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p2):

> If a **''shall''** or ''shall not'' requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime- constraint is violated, **the behavior is undefined.**[...]

---

However (I guess it is) POSIX prescribes the common extension [J.5.11](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.11):

> J.5.11 Multiple external definitions
>
> There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or without the explicit use of the keyword `extern`; if the definitions disagree, or more than one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).