# External variable declaration and definition

Tags: c, variables, external, declaration, definition

a)The definition of an external variable is same as that of a local variable,ie, `int i=2;` (only outside all functions). 
But why is `extern int i=2;` too working as the definition? Isn't `extern` used only in variable declaration in other files?

b)file 1

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int i=3;
  int main()
  {
      printf("%d",i);
      fn();
  }
```

file2

```
  int i;  //  although the declaration should be: extern int i; So, why is this working?
  void fn()
  {
      printf("%d",i);
  }
```

OUTPUT: 3 in both cases

Comment: The edit to your question is odd. I don't think you actually copied in the code that you used. For example, your call to `fn()` in file 1 is outside the `main` function! And you mean `int main(void)` rather than `int main()`.

Comment: This other doubt also cropped up, so i edited it. And yes, i didn't copy the code, i typed it. Thanks for pointing out the error. It's now correct.And int main() works just fine in my compiler.

Comment: So, any explanation for the second one?

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For historical reasons, the rules for determination of linkage and when a declaration provides a definition are a bit of a mess.

For your particular example, at file scope

```
extern int i = 2;
```

and

```
int i = 2;
```

are equivalent external definitions, ie `extern` is optional if you provide an initializer.

However, if you do not provide an initializer, `extern` is *not* optional:

```
int i;
```

is a *tentative definition* with external linkage, which becomes an external definition equivalent to

```
int i = 0;
```

if the translation unit doesn't contain another definition with explicit initializer.

This is different from

```
extern int i;
```

which is never a definition. If there already is another declaration of the same identifier visible, then the variable will get its linkage from that; if this is the first declaration, the variable will have external linkage.

This means that in your second example, both file1 and file2 provide an external definition of `i`, which is undefined behaviour, and the linker is free to choose the definition it likes best (it may also try to make demons fly out of your nose). There's a common extension to C (see C99 Annex J.5.11 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking)) which makes this particular case well-defined.

Comment: The examples in the standard contradict this answer.

Comment: You explanation seems to agree with what K & R has to say.

Comment: But why should extern int i=2; work when extern is used only in declaration and not in definitions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: which examples?

Comment: @rudra: `extern` can be used in definitions - however, if you use `extern`, you only get a definition if you also provide an initializer

Comment: But in a single file program, inside main() extern int i=2; gives the following error: "'i' has both extern and initializer". So it cannot be a valid definition syntax!

Comment: Although it's a valid definition in a multifile program!

Comment: @rudra: the rules for file-scope and block-scope declarations are different -- your particular case is explicitly disallowed by C99 6.7.8 §5: *If the declaration of an identifier has block scope, and the identifier has external or internal linkage, the declaration shall have no initializer for the identifier.*

Comment: @chirstopher one more thing. If in the second file i replace int i; by i = 3; it gives an error for multiple definitions. How is i=3; definition?

Comment: @Christoph I was mis-reading the standard. The key to this is the common extension.

Answer (score 1):

In C, an `extern` with an initialization results in a variable being allocated. That is the declaration will be considered a defining declaration. This is in contrast with the more common use of `extern`.

The C standard says:

> **6.9.2 External object definitions**
>
> .....
>
> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and an initializer, the
>   declaration is an external definition for the identifier.

As for the second part of your question, your declaration `int i` at file scope has external linkage. If you want to give it internal linkage you need to declare it `static int i`. The C standard says:

> **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**
>
> ......
>
> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

Comment: while it's true that the line `int i;` in file2 provides a declaration with external linkage, it's also a tentative definition; this means both file1 and file2 provide a definition of the same external identifier, which is undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Christoph No, the definition in file1 is not a tentative declaration.

Comment: file1 provides an external definition, file2 a tentative definition which also becomes an external definition at end of translation unit