# Linker doesn't show any error, weird

Tags: c, linker, static-linking, extern, linkage

Suppose i have 2 C src files, A1.C, A2.C, these are the contents:

A1.C

```
int x;
int main(){
     void f(void);

     x = 5; 
     f();
     printf("%d", x);

     return 0;
}
```

A2.C

```
int x;
void f() {  x = 4; }
```

the linker doesn't give me any errors despite the missing "extern" safe-word. i have 2 identical symbols. can someone explain why?

Comment: Did you try to add some warning options like `-W` (for GCC) and so on ... ?

Comment: I believe that if you don't have extern the compiler will remove one of the redundant variables

Comment: @apache It's unlikely. If it happens as you say, then the `extern` keywork would be useless. But maybe, the compiler consider the two variables as `static`. It would be easier to know if the question included the output produced by such a code.

Comment: @Unda: They are declared to have external linkage. Not giving a storage-class specifier means “external linkage” and `extern` means “linkage as already given, if none was given, external”.

Answer (score 2):

For gcc, you can use the `-fno-common` flag to turn this into an error.

The gcc documentation explains what's happening

> **-fno-common**
>
> In C code, controls the placement of uninitialized global variables. Unix C compilers have traditionally permitted multiple
>   definitions of such variables in different compilation units by
>   placing the variables in a common block. This is the behavior
>   specified by -fcommon, and is the default for GCC on most targets.
>
> On
>   the other hand, this behavior is not required by ISO C, and on some
>   targets may carry a speed or code size penalty on variable references.
>
> The -fno-common option specifies that the compiler should place
>   uninitialized global variables in the data section of the object file,
>   rather than generating them as common blocks. This has the effect that
>   if the same variable is declared (without extern) in two different
>   compilations, you get a multiple-definition error when you link them.

See also [Tentative definitions in C99 and linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490693/tentative-definitions-in-c99-and-linking)