# extern keyword with function names

Tags: c, linker, extern, non-static

I know that `static` keyword makes a C function/variable is file-scoped.
And I've read that If I want to make a variable global scope (accessed by more than one file), I should do:

in the `.c` file:

```
int my_global_var;

// main()....
```

in the `.h` file:

```
extern int my_global_var;
```

So, any one will include my `.h` file will be able to reference `my_global_var` which is already `extern`ed.

And I read also this is required for functions as well but I am using `gcc` 4.x and I don't `extern` the function in the .h file and other programs can successfully `link` it.

So, the question is...

Is the behavior of the non-static function linkage is the default or should I `extern` non-static functions to adhere to the ***standard***??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly use the extern keword in c.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keword-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

From the standard, 6.2.2

> **5** If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class
>   specifier, its linkage is determined
>   exactly as if it were declared with
>   the storage-class specifier extern. If
>   the declaration of an identifier for
>   an object has file scope and no
>   storage-class specifier, its linkage
>   is external.

Meaning, it's  extern by default.

Answer (score 1):

Both function and object declarations are `extern` by default. However, you need to add an explicit `extern` to your object declarations in header files to avoid a re-definition: without a storage-class specifier, any file-scoped object declaration will actually be something called a *tentative definition* and reserve storage for the object within the current translation-unit.

For consistency, I unnecessarily use `extern` even for function declarations. In most cases, I declare objects within headers as one of

```
extern int foo;
static const int bar = 42;
```

and functions as one of

```
extern int spam(void);
static inline int eggs(void) { return 42; }
```