# Linking error (#ifndef doesn't work as expected)

Tags: c++

Can't understand what is a problem here:
I have got main.cpp file where I am including:

```
#include "lexan.h"
...
```

The lexan.h file:

```
#ifndef _LEXAN_
#define _LEXAN_
enum Statements ...
//some function prototypes
...
struct TokensList {
    Statements statement;
    std::string value;
    struct TokensList *next;
};
struct TokensList *tokens = NULL;
#endif _LEXAN_
```

In lexan2.h:

```
#include "lexan.h"
// and some function prototypes
```

The problem is that I get the link error 2005:

```
1>lexan2.obj : error LNK2005: "struct TokensList * tokens" (?tokens@@3PAUTokensList@@A) already defined in lexan.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct TokensList * tokens" (?tokens@@3PAUTokensList@@A) already defined in lexan.obj
```

Where is my mistake? I thought the

```
#ifndef _LEXAN_
#define _LEXAN_
```

in the lexan.h file would protect me from such linking problems.

Comment: Show the code where you are creating `struct TokensList * tokens`. Most likely you are creating it in the header file `lexan.h` and then including the header in both `lexan.cpp` & `lexan2.cpp` which violates the **One Definition Rule(ODR)**.

Comment: I have just updated the question you can see now that struct TokensList *tokens is defined right after the struct TokensList definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating `struct TokensList * tokens` in the header file `lexan.h` and then including the header in both `lexan.cpp` & `lexan2.cpp` which violates the **[One Definition Rule(ODR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.

Note that, header guards prevent including the same header in the same **[Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**. When you create a variable in the header file, a copy of the variable with the same name gets created in every translation unit where you include the header. This leads to multiple same named variables in your project which the linker complains about.

**Solution:**
If you need to share it across files, you need to use `extern`.

**How to use `extern`?**
Have a look at:
[What are extern variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)
[How to correctly use the `extern` keyword in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keword-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You are violating the one definition rule, as hinted in comments.

Header files should declare variables; they should (almost) never define variables.  Your header is defining the variable `tokens`, which means that only one source file in a given program can use the header, which is not what was intended.

I suggest taking a look at [What are `extern` variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/) for an extensive (possibly too extensive) discussion of how to handle variables in headers.

But the fundamental rule is:

- Do not *define* variables in headers; only *declare* them.

Of course, that assumes that the global variable is necessary.  When you can, avoid them.  But when they are necessary, the header should declare, not define, the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Include guards only stop you from processing the same header twice *per translation unit* (source file).

Let's say you have a header, `X.h`, which has include guards:

```
// x.h
#ifndef X_H
#define X_H

    // x.h stuff

#endif
```

You also have `A.h` and `B.h`, each of which include `X.h`:

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

    #include "x.h"

    // a.h stuff

#endif

// b.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

    #include "x.h"

    // b.h stuff

#endif
```

Then we have `j.cpp` and `k.cpp`:

```
// j.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

    // j.cpp stuff

// k.cpp
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

    // k.cpp stuff
```

Here the include guards prevent `x.h` from being processed twice within `j.cpp`, likewise in `k.cpp`. *But `x.h` is still included twice, once for each translation unit.* So if `// x.h stuff` was this:

```
int myGlobalInt; // x.h stuff
```

Although you prevent `j.cpp` (and `k.cpp`) from defining this variable twice, each still has defined it once. At link time, the linker finds them both and complains.

What you want — other than avoiding global variables, which you should try to do — is this:

```
extern int myGlobalInt; // x.h stuff
```

Now each translation unit gets told "there exists a `myGlobalInt` somewhere", and you can explicit define it in a single translation unit of your choosing.

Also, don't use those kinds of header guards; names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital, as well as those beginning with two consecutive underscores [are reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).