# Accessing main program global structs/pointers from a dlopen()ed dynamic library in C on OS X

Tags: c, macos, pointers, gcc

I'm actually porting a Linux app to Mac OS X.  My problem is that I can access the variables but not the pointers.

I declared the variables in the `main.h` this way:

```
uint64_t test;
uint64_t *test2;
```

In the `mylib.h`:

```
extern uint64_t test;
extern uint64_t *test2;
```

and in `mylib.c` I access the variables this way:

```
printf("%llu\n",test);
printf("%llu\n",*test2);
```

The first `printf()` doesn't have any problems but the second gives me this error:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000008
```

Does anybody know why this happened?

My `ggc` command line has the following flags:

```
gcc -Wall -g -fPIC -c main.c gcc -shared -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -o mylib.so mylib.o
```

Comment: Has test2 been assigned a valid pointer?

Comment: That's a curious command line.  Are you producing a program called `mylib.so`?  And since you're linking `main.o` (indirectly; you specify `main.c` on the command line) and `mylib.o` on the command line, what are you using `dlopen()` on?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: There's a `-shared` in there, which ends up generating a shared library on Mac OS X.

Comment: @duskwuff: OK; so do we have to assume, then, that `main.c` does not actually contain a `main()` function instead?  Or is this a shared library with a `main()` in it? I'm still a little puzzled by the scenario.  We haven't seen the `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` code...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler of course the main.c contains a main() but i'm sure there isn't a problem with `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` because i can access other elements of `mylib.so` without problems only the pointers (in this case test2) make problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for someone with a similar problem:

I decided to work with getter & setter because there wasn't problems to access the function of the main program with a dynamic library just the variables.

in mylib.c :

```
test2 = getTest();
```

in main.c :

```
uint64_t* getTest(){
    return &test;
}
```

## Update

I finally found a way around this getter & setter. The problem you are facing is that you're defining your variable twice, in my case this happened during a misunderstanding of the `extern` keyword. To solve your problem you need to declare the variables as extern in your `main.h` e.g.:

```
extern uint64_t test;
extern uint64_t *test2;
```

Next step is to define the variables in your `main.c` e.g.:

```
int main(...) {
    test = 1;
    test2 = &test;
}
```

And finally remove the extern declaration from your `mylib.h`

The following SO post led to my solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c%E2%80%8B)