# How do define global variable visible across several .c files

Tags: c

assume there is a header file： a.h
and source file : a1.c  a2.c ... an.c;  n>=1， which means it may only have one source file, or have several source files.

my question is that how to define a global variable g in a.h; which should be visible by a1.c ... an.c.

there are  restrictions:

1. in a1.c a2.c ... an.c;  "a.h" can only be included in the first line,  which means there should be no code in the source file before the line of #include "a.h"
2. g must be defined in the a.h.
3. can only compile the code by the following way:

   ```
   gcc -c a1.c  -o  a1.o
   ...       
   gcc -c an.c  -o  an.o
   gcc  -o a.exe    a1.o ... an.o
   ```

there is an answer that define g in a.h like this:
    extern int g;
however, according to the c's specification J.5.11; it's undefined behavior.

is there any other solution?

Comment: You need to learn how to capital first letter of the sentence.

Comment: You're looking for the [`extern`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) keyword.

Comment: See: [**How to correctly use the extern keyword in C**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share a variable between source files in C? With \`extern\`, but how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)

Answer (score 4):

As you said, variable must be defined in the c file and declaration should be located in header file.
You have to define a global variable in any c file and declare 'extern' in header file.

Example)

```
1) define global variable in a1.c
    int g;

2) declare global variable in a.h
    extern int g;

3) include header file in other c files
    #include "a.h"
    // to do something
```