# Pointer to Structure

Tags: pointers, structure, extern

I am trying to study a code which I havent written.

In the below code a struct ICB_CMD_ is defined, and then *ICB_PCMD , is ICB_PCMD pointer to ICB_CMD_ ??

```
typedef struct ICB_CMD_
{
    UINT8  u8MsgId;
    UINT8  u8Addr;
    UINT8  u8Length;
    UINT8  u8MainCmd;
    UINT8  u8SubCmd;
    UINT8  au8Data[BUFFER_LENGTH-5];  //5: ENQ/ACK/NAK ID #BYTES CRCH CRCL  BUFFER_LENGTH=200
}*ICB_PCMD;
```

also then

```
EXTERN ICB_PCMD icb_pRxCmd;
EXTERN ICB_PCMD icb_pTxCmd;
```

What does the below 2 lines do ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above `*ICB_PCMD` is a pointer type to a type of `struct ICB_CMD_`, and it's not initialized yet.

The `extern` makes a variable visible in other source modules.

In this code both way of declaration can be used:

`struct ICB_CMD_ *var2;`

or

`ICB_PCMD var3;`

Both pointers :

`extern ICB_PCMD icb_pRxCmd;`

`exterb ICB_PCMD icb_pTxCmd;`

are external, which means they are declared in other file(s) but now (with `extern`) are accessible in the current source module.

Comment: Thank you,  So icb_pRxCMd and icb_pTxCmd are pointers to Struct ICB_CMD_ as well ?

Comment: If to be precise they are pointers of type `*ICB_PCMD` which is pointer to `struct ICB_CMD_`, see my edited answer, and the *ICB_PCMD is also type, type of pointer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The "extern" keyword allows you to access variables declared in another source file.

Here's some useful reading material on the subject:

StackOverflow - [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c)
StackOverflow - [How to correctly use the extern keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c)
[Understanding “extern” keyword in C](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/)