# Trying to understand extern in C

Tags: c, declaration, definition, extern

By the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499330/3121568), I am trying to construct a working example and try to understand behavior of the extern linkage.

Here is my example:

**extern.h**

```
extern int global_counter;

int file_counter;
```

**extern.c**

```
#include "extern.h"

int global_counter = 5;
```

**incrementor1.c**

```
#include "extern.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementor1_global()
{
    global_counter++;
    printf("From Incrementor1...\n");
    printf("Global counter is: %d\n", global_counter);
}

void incrementor1_local()
{
    file_counter++;
    printf("From Incrementor1...\n");
    printf("File counter is: %d\n", file_counter);
}
```

**incrementor2.c**

```
#include "extern.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementor2_global()
{
    global_counter++;
    printf("From Incrementor2...\n");
    printf("Global counter is: %d\n", global_counter);
}

void incrementor2_local()
{
    file_counter++;
    printf("From Incrementor2...\n");
    printf("File counter is: %d\n", file_counter);
}
```

You can yourself put these into separate files as depicted. Here is my main.c now:

**main.c**

```
void incrementor1_global();
void incrementor1_local();

void incrementor2_global();
void incrementor2_local();

int main(char argc, char* argv[])
{
    incrementor1_global();
    incrementor2_global();

    incrementor1_local();
    incrementor2_local();
}
```

Since I link .o files to my main, I am just declaring the functions and since they are extern by default, they are linked by the linker as I understood. And lastly, here is a makefile if you want to try it yourself.

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-I.

DEPS = extern.h

OBJ = main.o extern.o incrementor1.o incrementor2.o  

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)


.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

So by the answer linked above, I think global_counter should be shared by all translation units while each should have their own copy of file_counter. But the output I get is:

```
From Incrementor1...
Global counter is: 6
From Incrementor2...
Global counter is: 7
From Incrementor1...
File counter is: 1
From Incrementor2...
File counter is: 2
```

So, I think both incrementor have a one copy of file_counter and that is a global variable. But now I don't know how I can replicate the answer given and make them have their own copy. Any suggestions?

By the way, If I want to give a definition to file_counter in extern.h, since it is included in both incrementors I am getting multiple definitions error. This confuses me further on how could I make them have a shared copy.

Comment: `int file_counter` is a "tentative definition" and it is bad practice to put any data/function definitions in a header file. When such a header is included by two or more source files, they will define the same symbols and the linker may possibly complain.

Comment: What you are seeing is not the behaviour defined by the C standard, but it is recognized as a common extension in Annex J of the C11 standard (and in corresponding places in earlier versions of the standard).  It isn't guaranteed to work; it usually will work, but it is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int file_counter` is a tentative definition and is a global variable (with external linkage), as it is defined outside of any function. It is a good practice to have variable definitions in C source files, not in headers.

If you want each translation unit to have its own copy of `file_counter`, one way is to mark it as `static` and define it both in `incrementor1.c` and `incrementor2.c`. In that case, the visibility of the variable will be restricted only to the file in which it is defined.

Comment: If `int file_counter` also has external linkage, why it behaves differently than `extern int file_counter`? As far as I understood, `extern` gives us external linkage.

Comment: When you do a "extern int file_counter", you are just declaring the variable, saying it is defined elsewhere. Basically, you are ensuring one definition and telling other files that it exists and they can use it. When you remove the extern keyword, it also includes the definition which causes your multiple definition error.

Answer (score 3):

You're experiencing the *problem* due to tentative definition.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.2

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and
>   without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier `static`, constitutes a
>   tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an
>   identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
>   equal to 0.

Try compiling with `-fno-common` flag and it should throw the error related to redefinition for `file_counter`.

Quoting the [online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options)

> `-fno-common`
>
> In C code, this option controls the placement of global variables defined without an initializer, known as tentative definitions in the C standard. Tentative definitions are distinct from declarations of a variable with the extern keyword, which do not allocate storage.
>
> Unix C compilers have traditionally allocated storage for uninitialized global variables in a common block. This allows the linker to resolve all tentative definitions of the same variable in different compilation units to the same object, or to a non-tentative definition. This is the behavior specified by -fcommon, and is the default for GCC on most targets. On the other hand, this behavior is not required by ISO C, and on some targets may carry a speed or code size penalty on variable references.
>
> The -fno-common option specifies that the compiler should instead place uninitialized global variables in the data section of the object file. This inhibits the merging of tentative definitions by the linker so you get a multiple-definition error if the same variable is defined in more than one compilation unit. Compiling with -fno-common is useful on targets for which it provides better performance, or if you wish to verify that the program will work on other systems that always treat uninitialized variable definitions this way.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your compilation units that includes `extern.h` declares a variable called `file_counter` at global scope. That means that each one declares the variable and some storage for it, but the variable is theoretically visible at link time to other compilation units.

When the linker comes along, it sees these global variables and allocates them to a segment of storage and, in your case, it coalesces them into one instance, I'm not sure if this is mandated by the C standard or not, I'm too lazy to check, but it's probably an example of undefined behaviour.

What you need is to make the variable `file-counter` be visible only in the compilation unit in which it is declared (the `.c` file that included the `.h`) and for that, you use the `static` modifier

```
static int file_counter;
```

As a rule, it should also be removed from the header and placed in the `.c` file where it is going to be used. It's OK for your toy example that demonstrates the difference between `extern` and `static` but in pretty much every real scenario, you do not want a new static variable in every single `.c` file that includes the header.

Answer (score 0):

> So by the answer linked above, I think global_counter should be shared by all translation units while each should have their own copy of file_counter

This is incorrect. Both `global_counter` and `file_counter` are global variables. This is because you declare `file_counter` outside any function.

If you declare `file_counter` separately inside the functions `incrementor1_local` and `incrementor2_local` and remove it from `extern.h`, then it will be a local variable and will have separate copies in each function.

Comment: Is it incorrect in the sense that I misunderstood the answer or that the answer is incorrect? Because that answer says each translation unit should have separate copy of errno.