# understanding of extern storage class

Tags: c, extern

Can you please someone explain me the flow of below problem,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   extern int a;
   printf("%d\n",a);
   return 0;
}

int a = 20;
```

and the output is 20. I am not sure where is the variable a getting defined and where is it getting declared?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 2):

The variable `a` is declared and defined as a **global variable** in the line:

```
int a = 20;
```

The `extern` line just tells the `main()` function scope that `a` is defined in another place.

In this case, the use of `extern` is not really necessary. You could just declare and define `a` *before* the `main()` function, and then `main()` would be familiar with it.

Usually, you would use `extern` when you want to use a variable or a function that was defined **in another source file** (and not just later in the same source file).

Answer (score 2):

`extern` is syntactically a "storage class" keyword. But there is no such storage class. C has "static storage", "dynamic storage (`malloc`, etc) and "automatic storage" (local variables, usually represented using a stack).

If an identifier is declared `extern` inside a block scope, it means that the declaration refers to an external definition. If the entity  being declared is an object, then it has static storage, simply because external objects have static storage. It can be a function too; functions aren't said to have storage.

In C, there is a concept called "linkage". Objects declared outside of any function at file scope, and functions, can have "external" or "internal" linkage.

If we have `extern` in a block scope, as you have in the example program, there can be a prior declaration of the same name at file scope, or in a nested scope, like this:

```
static int x;

/* ... */

  {
    extern int x;
  }
```

Here, the inner `x` refers to the outer `x`, and, in spite of being "extern", it has internal linkage because of the "static".

In a nutshell, `extern` usually means "refer to the earlier declaration, and if there isn't one, declare this as an identifier with external linkage".

The word "external" refers to two separate concepts: the aforementioned "external linkage" and also to the meaning "outside of any function", as in "external declaration".  Confusingly, "external declarations", like the `static int x` above, can have "internal linkage"!

In your program, things are correct because the block scope `extern` declaration of `a` and the later `int a = 20`, which are in separate scopes, happen to *independently* agree with each other.

The `int a = 20;` is an external declaration, which is also an external definition (because of the initializer). Since in that scope, no prior declaration of `a` is visible, it gets external linkage.

So, where is `a` defined? It is defined as an object with external linkage, in the entire translation unit as a whole. That translation unit is what defines `a`.  `a` is declared in every place of the program where a declaration appears; and its definition is also a declaration. It is declared in `main` and also in the last line of the translation unit's source code.

A "declaration" is syntax which makes a name known in some scope. It's a concept that is active during the translation of a program. A "definition" is the fact that some object or function is provided in some translation unit. Translated units still provide definitions, but need not retain information about declarations. (Which is why when we make libraries, we provide header files with declarations in them!)

From the point of view of your `main` function, that function doesn't "care" where `a` is defined. It has declared `a` in such a way that if `a` is used, then an external definition of `a`, with external linkage, must exist. That definition could come from anywhere: it could be in the same translation unit, or in another translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

The C programming language has been designed to be one-pass, so that the compiler *could* process each line only once from top to bottom. So considering your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   extern int a;
   printf("%d\n",a);
   return 0;
}

int a = 20;
```

The identifier `a` is declared twice, and defined once.

Before the 4th line `extern int a;`, the compiler doesn't know anything about the identifier `a`. The *declaration* `extern int a;` has the block scope within the function `main`, and it declares the identifier `a` as an `int` and that its storage duration is *static* and linkage is *external*. So the compiler can write code that access a global identifier by name `a` as an `int` variable that *could* be defined in another module (external linkage). This is what the compiler does on line `5` when it is used in `printf`.

Finally at line 9, `int a = 20;` is another declaration *and* definition. This declares and defines `a` as a `int` with static storage duration, and external linkage.

If you'd put the `int a = 20;` before the `main`, the declaration `extern int a;` would be useless, because it doesn't add anything. I tend to put my `main` and other depending functions *last* in my source code, so that minimal amount of extra declarations are needed.

Comment: In the C standard, the terms used for the storage duration are 'static duration' vs 'thread duration', 'automatic duration' or 'allocated duration'.  Similarly, it is 'internal linkage' vs 'external linkage' vs 'no linkage' for name visibility.  The storage class on `a` is not `static`, but its storage duration is static.  'Tis tricky — I'm probably guilty of sloppiness on occasion, too.

Comment: Oops true dat :d

Answer (score 0):

When ever you declare a variable as `extern` then It means that Variable is declared as global and you cannot initialize the variable there.Because no memory is allocated for that variable It is just declared as a Variable 
you can define it some where in your code.

Let us take an example ..consider the code

```
int main()
{
extern int i;
i=10;
printf("%d",sizeof(i));
}
```

here you get an error that `int 'i' is not defined`

therefore you need to write it as:

```
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    int i=10;
    printf("%d",sizeof(i));
}
```

In case of your code:
This is declaration

```
extern int a;
```

This is definition:

```
int a = 20;
```

Comment: **When ever you declare a variable as extern then It means that Variable is declared as global**. Can you explain this ?

Comment: I think you mean to say that the a variable declared as `extern` is declared global in some other file, but it can be local to function in the files where we provide its declaration.

Comment: A variable declared as `extern`  is a global. You can give definition to it at any where in your program even out side of your main function.

Comment: If you need such kind of stuff .You can go through the book called **Test your C skills** by yeshwanth kanethkar. [link](http://www.amazon.in/Test-Your-Skills-Yashavant-Kanetkar/dp/8183331181)  or you can get free online pdf version

Answer (score 0):

The storage class `extern` specifies storage duration and linkage of the object the identifier refers to:

The storage duration is set to *static*, which means the variable is alive for the whole time the program runs. As you declare that variable inside a function scope, this matters in your example, because in function scope, the default storage duration would be *automatic*.

The linkage is set to *external*, this just means different translation units of the same program can share the object. It has the side effect that a *definition* in another (file) scope is acceptable, as shown in your example. This is a logical consequence of the *shared* nature, you would typically declare a variable with external linkage in all translation units using it, but define it only in one.