# The good ol' LNK2001

Tags: c++, header, linker

I have 3 headers
`DirectX.h`,`Draws.h`,`Memory.h` d

Every function has a definition in its corresponding .cpp so that is ruled out except for DirectX.h ofc
I tried a set of solutions to fix it but without success, like not `including` stdafx.h in all on the Headers.

A little snippet of the three

**Memory.h**

```
        #pragma once
        #include "stdafx.h"
        Class Memory
        {
        foo.. 
        };
        extern Memory *gMemory;
```

**Draws.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
Class Drawing
{
foo..
};
extern Drawing *Draw;
```

**DirectX.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
struct Direct
{
foo
};
extern Direct *DirectX;
```

**Error**

```
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Memory * gMemory" (?gMemory@@3PAVMemory@@A)
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class Drawing * Draw" (?Draw@@3PAVDrawing@@A)
1>dllmain.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct Direct * DirectX" (?DirectX@@3PAUDirect@@A)
1>Draws.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct Direct * DirectX" (?DirectX@@3PAUDirect@@A)
```

**stdafx.h**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#include "Memory.h"
#include "Draws.h"
#include "DirectX.h"
```

**dllmain.cpp**
The only parts where I'm using the extern are

```
gMemory->FindPattern(..);
if (!DirectX->Line)
    {
    D3DXCreateLine(pDevice, &DirectX->Line);
    }
    Draw->Circle(foo);
```

Comment: Show us `dllmain.cpp`. It seems, that you never defined objects `gMemory`, `Draw` and `DirectX`

Comment: Using `extern` does not create the vars. Are they declared somewhere else? [How to correctly use the extern keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496448/669576)

Comment: No, they are not, so what should I do to use with the extern? Declare them before and the extern the variable?

Answer (score 0):

`extern` keyword means, that object is defined somewhere else (in other compilation unit, in linked static lib), in simple words, it's link to the objects, that are instantiated (created) somewhere else, but can be used in the current compilation unit.

In you `dllmain.cpp` you should declare variables in global (for example) scope:

```
// Declaration of pointers.
Drawing* Draw = NULL;
Direct* DirectX = NULL;
Memory* gMemory = NULL;
```

and in `int dllmain()` (or whatever main function you have):

```
// Initialization of pointers with newly created objects:
Draw = new Drawing();
DirectX = new Direct();
gMemory = new Memory();
```

Comment: Ok but I use then at the Drawing.h how would I approach extending the object scope to that?

Comment: `extern Drawing* Draw;` already does what you wants: object will be declared in `dllmain.cpp` but available in `Drawing.h` too

Comment: Thanks guys it really clarified a lot for me!