# How can I refer to a variable in another C file?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have a variable in a C file called list.c and I initialize the var with the function initList(void) inside my main.c. How can I get the variable while being inside my main.c?

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

int main() {
    initList();
    return 0;
}
```

list.c:

```
#include "list.h"

listItem *firstItem;
listItem *currentItem;

void initList(void) {
    currentItem = calloc(1, sizeof(listItem));
    currentItem->data = 0;
    currentItem->lastItem = NULL;
    currentItem->nextItem = NULL;
    firstItem = currentItem;
}
void listInsert(int data) {
    listItem *newItem = calloc(1, sizeof(listItem));
    newItem->data = data;
    newItem->lastItem = currentItem;
    newItem->nextItem = NULL;
    currentItem = newItem;
}
```

list.h:

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

void initList(void);
void listInsert(int data);

typedef struct listItem {
    void *lastItem;
    void *nextItem;
    int data;
} listItem;

#endif
```

As you can see I initialize the variable in my initList(void) function which I call in the main.c file. Now I want to do something with my variable. For example I would like to insert something into the list with my function listInsert(int data) which does not work.

Does C not keep the reference to both my variables firstItem, currentItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In main.c you must put this:

```
extern listItem *firstItem;
extern listItem *currentItem;
```

This will let the compiler know that the two variables `firstItem` and  `firstItem` are declared in some other .c file.

This [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c) explains more about the `extern` keyword.

**EDIT**
But using `extern` here is most likely bad practice, because you could only have a single linked list in your whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Declare 'head' of list in header with `extern`

Suggest redesign of the `currentItem` variable, 'current' is specific for every algorithm

```
#ifndef PRAKTIKUM_1_LINKEDLIST_H

#define PRAKTIKUM_1_LINKEDLIST_H

extern listItem *firstItem;  // usually named 'head'

// bad pracite, local for concrete algoritm 
// listItem *currentItem;

void initList(void);
void listInsert(int data);

typedef struct listItem {
    void *lastItem;
    void *nextItem;
    int data;
} listItem;

#endif //PRAKTIKUM_1_LINKEDLIST_H
```

and such suggestion for functions

```
void initList(void) {
    listItem *currentItem;
...
}
void listInsert(int data) {
listItem *currentItem;
..
}
```