# Division between declaration and definition in other C files

Tags: c, constants, declaration, definition

I would like to know how make the division between declaration and definition. I read few related with this topic question but for now I can do this only in basic funtion. The problem is when I try to declare constant global variable in header file and I want use this constant in the function which have declaration in the same place but definition in other files. I have 2 files with .c extension and one with .h extension.

File main_lib.h consist:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_LIB_H_
#define _MAIN_LIB_H_
const int N_POINTS=10;

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};
void fill_random(struct Point points[], int n);
void closest(struct Point points[], int n, struct Point* p);

#endif /* _MAIN_LIB_H_ */
```

File main_lib.c consist:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include "main_lib.h"

    void fill_random(struct Point points[], int n){
...
    }
    void closest(struct Point points[], int n, struct Point* p){
...
    }
```

And the last file named main.c consist:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "main_lib.h"

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    struct Point random_points[N_POINTS];

    struct Point *p;
    p=&random_points[0];

    fill_random(p,N_POINTS);
    closest(p,N_POINTS,p);

    return 0;
}
```

The question is how to correct this code to run it without error status. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: `const int N_POINTS=10;` in the header (and twice included) will probably give a link error (something like multiple definitions). Instead, you can do this: `extern const in N_POINTS;` in the header and `const int N_POINTS=10;` in _one_ C source. The linker will ensure that all other C sources will be linked against the same `N_POINTS`.

Comment: Please, consider that `const` does not mean "constant" as you might think. Instead, it should be understood as "read-only". There are no constants in C except the literals (e.g. `123`) and values defined by an `enum`. (My personal memory hook: everything what you _may_ use e.g. as size of a global array declaration...)

Comment: Is `extern` mostly useful in this context only?

Comment: @Scheff Detail: In C, `123` is an integer _constant_.  C has 2 _literals_: _string literal_ and _compound literal_ - both of which may have their address taken, unlike _constants_. (Different from C++)

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo Depends on how you consider it - you declare functions as extern, too, so they are accessible from outside the file - just that extern is the default...

Comment: @chux I must admit that this term "literal" confuses me a bit. I tried to say it correct but I fully agree with your argument. I once tried to clarify this in google and Wikipedia but with less luck. This term is used in too many contexts with slightly different meanings... (But I don't give up. Once I will get it...)

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo My rule of thumb: If its globally declared and its not explicitly something else (e.g. `static`) or restricted by a previous declaration it's `extern`. The answers to [SO: How to correctly use the extern keyword in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496448/7478597) probably explain it better.

Comment: @Scheff Agree about "literal" confusion.  I try to use as the C spec as this is a C post - C spec uses it in a consistent manner/context - literally ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is when I try to declare constant global variable in header file  ...
>
> how to correct this code to run it without error status(?)

Instead, *declare* `extern` in main_lib.h  [@Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187398/division-between-declaration-and-definition-in-other-c-files/48187951#comment83354600_48187398).  This would be the same if the global variable was non-`const` or `volatile`.

```
// const int N_POINTS=10;
extern const int N_POINTS;
```

*Define* it once and only in main_lib.c

```
// add
const int N_POINTS=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

A method I often use is:

```
// lib.h
#ifndef EXTERN
#define EXTERN extern
#endif
EXTERN int myInt;

// lib.c
#include "lib.h"

// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "lib.h"
```

`myInt` will now be known in all modules in which `lib.h` is included but will only be declared once in `main.c`. Usefull when you have lots of includes.