# Are functions external by default?

Tags: c, function, extern

Is a function without a storage class specified in its declaration and definition :

```
void func(void); // declaration

void func(void) { // implementation
    
}
```

be equivalent to the function with extern storage class in its declaration and definition? :

```
extern void func(void); // declaration

extern void func(void) { // implementation
    
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been answered before (or I couldn't find it, also likely).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c for half credit

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, anyways, I am sure this question is going to get a lot of upvotes. ciapi1369,,,, wow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers)

> 5 If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no
> storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it
> were declared with the storage-class specifier extern. If the
> declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no
> storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

Comment: So this means that even the main function has external storage class by default?

Comment: Otherwise, how would the C runtime link to it and call it at runtime?

Comment: @ciapi1369 Yes, of course. It may not have internal linkage in a hosted environment.

Comment: @ciapi1369: No, functions do not have storage classes. Storage classes, or more properly, storage durations, are categories for the lifetimes of objects. `extern` and `static` are storage-class keywords, which are different from storage classes (the same way “fox” and “dog” are words for animals but are not animals). Storage-class keywords partly affect storage classes of objects, but they also affect linkages of identifiers and other things. The rules about them are a mishmash and a bit complicated due to the history of how C developed…

Comment: … Different C implementations did things in different ways, and the C standardization committee had to tie things together. The storage-class specifiers also affect linkage, which is the issue here. Linkage is the process by which declarations of identical identifiers in different places can be made to refer to the same object or function…

Comment: … Because of the complications in C history, the `extern` keyword also causes external linkage for identifiers in a new declaration, and `static` causes internal linkage. (In a redeclaration of a visible identifier, `extern` does not change the prior linkage; in `static int x; extern int x;`, `x` still has internal linkage in the latter. As stated, the rules are complicated.) All identifiers declared outside of functions have external linkage by default.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers for functions always have external linkage by default. Storage class is a separate issue.

Some rules about declarations are:

- For declarations outside of functions, all identifiers have external linkage by default.
- For declarations inside of functions, identifiers for functions have external linkage by default, and identifiers for objects have no linkage by default.
- If the declaration includes `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.

By these rules, identifiers for functions have external linkage by default, have internal linkage if declared with `static`, and never have no linkage. There are additional rules for declarations which are not fully described here. The rules are a mishmash and a bit complicated due to the history of how C developed. Different C implementations did things in different ways, and the C standardization committee had to tie things together.

Functions do not have storage classes. Storage classes, or more properly, storage durations, are categories for the lifetimes of objects. `extern` and `static` are keywords called storage-class specifiers, which are different from storage classes (the same way “fox” and “dog” are words for animals but are not animals). Storage-class specifiers partly affect storage classes of objects, but they also affect linkages of identifiers and other things. Linkage of function identifiers is the issue here, not storage class. Linkage is the process by which declarations of identical identifiers in different places can be made to refer to the same object or function. Because of the complications in C history, the `extern` keyword causes external linkage for identifiers in a new declaration, and `static` causes internal linkage. (In a redeclaration of a visible identifier, `extern` does not change the prior linkage; in `static int x; extern int x;`, `x` still has internal linkage in the latter. As stated, the rules are complicated.)