# Undefined reference variable using extern keyword

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, extern, undefined-reference

I have two C files in the same folder:

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;

int main()
{
    a = 1;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;

int main()
{
    a = 1;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

I run file2.c on vscode and its return:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Users\Duong\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8Tiaj4.o:file2.c:(.rdata$.refptr.a[.refptr.a]+0x0): undefined reference to `a'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have try many way sincluding add header file, but it doesn't work at all.

Can someone tell me if my code or my compiler has any problem

Comment: You clearly aren't compiling & linking both files, otherwise you'd have an error about having two `main` functions

Comment: For file2.c you would need to add some other .c file to the project that defines the `int a;` variable.

Comment: If you put `extern` on a variable that means you define the variable somewhere else. Your `file2.c` doesn't contain a definition of `a` (which is why the error is saying `a` is undefined), so you'd have to link it to something that does. If you didn't want to do that, just remove the `extern`.

Comment: [how to use `extern` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496448/how-to-correctly-use-the-extern-keyword-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to compile and link both files.
2. You can't have two functions with the same name. As you have `main` function defined in both files it proves that you do not link them together.

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int a;

int main()
{
    a = 1;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and link them from command line

```
gcc -o main file1.c file2.c
```

Visual studio code is not for a very beginners as it requires some configuration and understanding how thing work.

Install Eclipse CDT which manages the projects for you without problems

Answer (score 1):

No, your compiler is telling you the truth.  In `pru2.c` you have a `main()` routine (as in `pru1.c`) so I must assume both are *different programs*.

You have defined a variable in `pru2.c` that will be found in another compilation unit (module) of *the same program* (a process cannot access the memory of another, so you can acces no variables of another, different program)  For that variable to be viewable, both, `file1.c` and `file2.c` need to be compiled together (or better said, linked together) into a single problem. But that cannot be done, because you have one `main()` function on each, and when trying to link both compilation units together, you will get a linker error telling you that you have two definitions for `main` in the same program (which cannot be)

Just change the name of `main()` routine in one of the files to something different (you will not use it) and compile both modules together into the same program

```
cc -o pru2 file1.c file2.c
```

As the `main()` functions in both files are the same, just delete `main()` in `file1.c` makint it to appear as:

```
int a; /* just one variable in this compilation unit */
```

while `file2.c` remains the same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int a;
int main()
{
   a = 1;
   printf("a = %d\n", a);
}
```

and then you can compile them separately:

```
cc -c file1.c                  # compilations
cc -c file2.c
cc -o program file1.o file2.o  # this is the linker
```

or all together:

```
cc -o program file1.c file2.c
```